# Checking for null/empty float values when using sscanf

Tags: c, arrays, struct, scanf, fgets

The following program attempts to read an input file line by line using `fgets`, and save each `comma delimited` float value into an array of structs using `sscanf` (this aspect of the code works fine). The issue lies in that the program should also detect when a float value is missing/empty, and assign it the float value `1.500` which then is saved into the array of structs.

**EDIT:** This is supposed to be compiled using VS2017, so on Windows.

***Note:** Please note that the following questions have been studied before posting this question:

[How to check if a string returned by scanf is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126825/how-to-check-if-a-string-returned-by-scanf-is-null)

[How to get scanf to continue with empty scanset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974628/how-to-get-scanf-to-continue-with-empty-scanset)

An example of the input file (missing value in the second row):

```
0.123f, 0.234f, 0.345f, 0.456f, 0.567f
1.987f, , 7.376f, 2.356f, 5.122f
9.111f, 1.234f, 7.091f, 6.672f, 9.887f
```

Desired output (**missing value in second row is detected and set to 1.500**):

```
0.123 0.234 0.345 0.456 0.567
1.987 1.500 7.376 2.356 5.122
9.111 1.234 7.091 6.672 9.887
```

So far, the first attempt tried to scan all 5 floats (each with 'f' suffix) into strings and then check to see if those strings are null/empty or of zero length using `strcmp` and `strlen`, respectively, and finally involved trying to use `sscanf` again on each of those variables to read each into an array of structs.

The 2nd attempt included a check to see if the `sscanf` was successful by using `if (sscanf(line, "%ff", &data[i].x) == NULL) { // ...some alert and assign 1.500}`, which did not work either. The 3rd attempt, as seen below:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {

typedef struct {
    float x, y, vx, vy, mass;
}DATA;

    FILE *file = fopen("null_detector.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf(stderr, "ERROR: file not opened.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    int N= 3;
    DATA* data = malloc(Nbodies * sizeof * data); // Array allocation
    char line[256];
    int i;
    int inc = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < Nbodies; i += inc)
    {
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), file);

        // **Some info:
        // Scan 5 float variables per line (this part works fine)
        sscanf(line, "%ff, %ff, %ff, %ff, %ff",
            &data[i].x, &data[i].y, &data[i].vx, &data[i].vy, &data[i].mass); // %ff accounts for 'f' suffix

        // Now check if any of above vars are empty/NULL.
        // NOTE: aware that these vars CANNOT be compared to NULL,
        // but has been included to try and provide clarity for end goal
        if (data[i].x == NULL)
        {
            //.. assign 1.500 to data[i].x
        }
        if (data[i].y == NULL)
        {
            //... same as above etc
        }
        // ...Repeat IF statements for all 5 vars

    }

     //Print the contents of array of structs to check for correct output
    for (i = 0; i < Nbodies; i++)
    {
        printf("%.3f %.3f %.3f %.3f %.3f\n", data[i].x, data[i].y, data[i].vx, data[i].vy, data[i].mass);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Summary:**

Does anyone know how this program can be modified to:

- detect missing float values in each line of the file upon reading them with `fgets`
- replace missing float values with the float value `1.500`
- write these values to the array of structs, like the non-missing values successfully are doing?
- As commented in the code, I am aware that the **struct float variables cannot be compared to `NULL`**. I have included this comparison in the code to only try to add some clarity as to what the end goal is.

Comment: Take a look at `strtok`

Comment: @jiveturkey `strtok` doesn't scan empty fields, [strsep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html) does

Comment: Nicely formed question.

Comment: That's cool.  Never knew that one.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, in fact I'm going to reopen it because I didn't pay attention to the _Please note that the following questions have been studied before posting this question:_ part, and they are not answering to how to set a default value like 1.500

Comment: Whenever you use `scanf`, without exception,  *you must check its return value*. That might not be sufficient, but it is absolutely necessary. And you should understand what the return value means: it is the number of conversions stored in arguments. (It is *not* a pointer, so comparing it to `NULL` is meaningless.)

Comment: You cannot reliably tell if an argument to `scanf` has had its value filled in, since C does not have any concept of an "uninitialised" value. You can compare the value of an argument with its previous value, if you saved that somewhere, but that's not teliabke; the user might happen to enter that particular value. BUT, the return value of `scanf` is clear. If `scanf` returns 0, no arguments have been set. If it returns 1, only the first argument has been set. And so on.

Comment: @Rici That makes sense to me, I will play with the return value to check for 0 or 1 and post my working program when finished.

Comment: `NULL` is for pointers, not values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strsep` to separate each line.

```
str = strsep(&line, ",")
```

Using one function to set the value of data:

```
void set_data(DATA *dt, int count, float f) {
    switch(count) {
        case 0: dt->x = f; break;
        case 1: dt->y = f; break;
        case 2: dt->vx = f; break;
        case 3: dt->vy = f; break;
        case 4: dt->mass = f; break;
    }
}
```

The complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <unistd.h>  
#include <string.h>  
#include <stdlib.h> 

typedef struct {
    float x, y, vx, vy, mass;
}DATA;

void set_data(DATA *dt, int count, float f) {
    switch(count) {
        case 0: dt->x = f; break;
        case 1: dt->y = f; break;
        case 2: dt->vx = f; break;
        case 3: dt->vy = f; break;
        case 4: dt->mass = f; break;
    }
}

int main() {

    FILE *file = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf( "ERROR: file not opened.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    int N= 3;
    DATA* data = malloc(N * sizeof(data)); // Array allocation
    char *line;
    int i;
    int inc = 1;
    size_t n = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i += inc)
    {
        getline(&line, &n, file);
        int count = 0;
        char *str;
        while((str = strsep(&line, ",")) != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(str, " ") == 0) {
                set_data(&data[i], count, 1.5);
            } else {
                set_data(&data[i], count, atof(str));
            }
           // printf("count = %d\n", count);
            // printf("token: %s\n", str);
            count++;
        }

    }

     //Print the contents of array of structs to check for correct output
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%.3f %.3f %.3f %.3f %.3f\n", data[i].x, data[i].y, data[i].vx, data[i].vy, data[i].mass);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The input:

```
#cat text.txt
0.123f, 0.234f, 0.345f, 0.456f, 0.567f
1.987f, , 7.376f, 2.356f, 5.122f
9.111f, 1.234f, 7.091f, 6.672f, 9.887
```

The output:

```
0.123 0.234 0.345 0.456 0.567
1.987 1.500 7.376 2.356 5.122
9.111 1.234 7.091 6.672 9.887
```

Comment: This looks like what I was looking for, thank you very much for your help. I'm having some trouble with `#include <unistd.h>` as I'm working on VS2017 (I should have mentioned this in my question). I think I can use `#include <process.h>` instead, although I recieve the following two errors when compiling with <unistd.h>: `unresolved external symbol _getline reference in function main` and `unresolved external symbol _strsep reference in function main`. I will try to solve this and will post the solution when I am finished. Thanks again @Hitokiri

Comment: #include <unistd.h> does not need in this case, sorry, i did not do the attention. So you can delete include <unistd.h>. For getline in VS, you just include <string> instead of <string.h>

Comment: Great, I will give that a go. Again thank you for your help, very clear and easy to understand answer.

Comment: Apologies @Hitokiri, I will mark it as accepted again as it was close. It only works on Linux (this was my fault for not mentioning it in the questions, as I am in fact using VS2017). I have written a function for strsep but your solution only accounts for delimeters where there is a `comma` followed by a `space`, but in my example input sometimes there are no spaces between commas. I will keep working on this.

Comment: Try to make a funtion by yourself. Goodluck

Answer (score 1):

It can also achieved with only `sscanf` if there is at least a space between the commas when there is an absence of an input value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  char *str[] = {"0.123f, 0.234f, 0.345f, 0.456f, 0.567f",
                 "1.987f, , 7.376f, 2.356f, 5.122f",
                 "9.111f, 1.234f, 7.091f, 6.672f, 9.887f"};

  float float_arr[3][5];
  char temp[5][7];

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (5 != sscanf(str[i], "%6[^,],%6[^,],%6[^,],%6[^,],%6[^,]", 
                    temp[0], temp[1], temp[2], temp[3], temp[4]))
      return printf("Error\n"), 1;

    for (unsigned j = 0; j < 5; j++)
      if (1 != sscanf(temp[j], "%ff", &float_arr[i][j]))
        float_arr[i][j] = 1.500f;
  }

  // printing the result
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < 5; j++)
      printf("%ff ", float_arr[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
0.123000f 0.234000f 0.345000f 0.456000f 0.567000f 
1.987000f 1.500000f 7.376000f 2.356000f 5.122000f 
9.111000f 1.234000f 7.091000f 6.672000f 9.887000f
```

Comment: There typically isn't a space between the commas in a CSV data file when a field is empty.