# Transferring A std::stringstream

Tags: c++, c++11, network-programming, type-conversion, stringstream

Hello everyone and thank you very much for your time.

There is a std::stringstream that needs transferred to a remote machine.
The networking library allows me to construct a packet in the following method:

```
CreatePacket( const void * DATA, size_t DATA_SIZE )
```

On the receiving end the data is returned as a uint8_t*

What I cannot figure out is how to take the std::stringstream data, put it into the CreatePacket() function, then on the receiving end reconstruct a std::stringstream from the uint8_t* and doing so in the most efficient manner.

As a side note the stringstream holds binary data.

Thank you all again for your time I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Have you looked at your favorite C++ reference to find all the methods of `std::stringstream`?  Looks like there is a method `str()` that may be of some use.

Comment: Yes I was converting the stringstream into a std::string then transferring with the strings c_str function but I was unsure if there was a more efficient way. Reconstructing the stringstream on the receiving end from the uint8_t* was where I was most confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/str) member function to obtain an [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) from the `stringstream`. Then use the `c_str()` or `data()` member functions to get access to the string's internal buffer.

```
auto s = myStringStream.str();
CreatePacket(s.data(), s.size());
```

Comment: Thank you very much, how about reconstructing the stringstream from uint8_t* on the receiving end?

Comment: Hmmm, what about **i**stringstream?

Comment: I am using std::ostringstream on the senders end and std::istringstream on the receiver's end but am unsure on how to actually get the uint8_t* into the istringstream. Thank you very much for your patience.

Comment: @KKlouzal The easiest way would be to construct a `string` using the constructor that takes a pointer to the buffer and length. You can then construct an `istringstream` using this `string`. If you want to get fancy and avoid data copying, you'll have to implement a class that derives from [`basic_streambuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf). Then pass an instance of this class to the `istringstream`.

Comment: Okay thank you again, I don't need to get too fancy :) Typecasting is the only way here? std::string((const char*)event.packet->data, event.packet->dataLength);

Comment: @KKlouzal Assuming `event.packet->data` is a `void *`, that looks fine. A more *C++-y* expression would be `std::string(static_cast<const char*>(event.packet->data), event.packet->dataLength);`

Comment: Thank you both so much it's working now! event.packet->data returns uint8_t* Does using static_cast have any benefits over typecasting?

Comment: @KKlouzal [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/103868/241631) explains the difference.