# What is the difference between a reinterpret_cast and a C-style cast?

Tags: c++, casting

What is the difference between :

```
double x = 10.3;
int y;
y = (int) x;    // c-like cast notation
```

And :

```
double x = 10.3;
int y;
y = reinterpret_cast<int>(x)
```

Comment: A language tag would be good here.  C++?

Comment: For reference, the doc page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0w9f63b.aspx.

Comment: Or check this answer: [Regular cast vs. static_cast vs. dynamic_cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast?rq=1) which also includes reinterpret_cast

Comment: To put it simply, C-style cast can do nearly everything. static_cast is limited to less dangerous forms of casting, so you are less likely to make a bad cast by accident. reinterpret_cast is most similar to C-style cast and shouldn't be used for number type conversion.

Answer (score 3):

A C-style cast can be any of the following types of casts:

- `const_cast`
- `static_cast`
- `static_cast` followed by a `const_cast`
- `reinterpret_cast`
- `reinterpret_cast` followed by a `const_cast`

the first one from that list that can be done is the what the C-style cast will perform (from C++03 5.4: "Explicit type conversion (cast notation)"

So for your example:

```
double x = 10.3;
int y;
y = (int) x;
```

the type of cast used would be a `static_cast`.

And `y = reinterpret_cast<int>(x);` won't compile.