# C++ casting idiom

Tags: c++, casting

What's the standard idiom for general casting in C++ these days?

The C idiom is:

```
(int)t.
```

I've been using:

```
static_cast<int>(t).
```

But I'm most comfortable with:

```
int(t).
```

What do the gurus do?

Comment: You *should* use `static_cast` in C++ for the example you've shown. But I often see people get lazy and C-style case for basic types such as `int`.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103512/in-c-why-use-static-castintx-instead-of-intx

Comment: @Cyber: Nope, you shouldn't. Depending on what `t` is. Just because there is more to read doesn't mean it's more readable.

Comment: Not sure this is a duplicate.  I know the difference between static_cast and C-style casting.  I'm after the idiom here and what's considered good/bad and why.

Comment: @Robinson See the second link I posted.

Comment: BTW: The C part is not idiom, but the only way in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ style cast is always preferable. I could cite three good reasons for preferring C++ casts over C-style cast:-

1) They helps in readability. Anyone with one glance at your code get to know that cast is used whereas it's not the case with C-style casts.

2) There are 4 different casts in C++ which clearly express the intent of the programmer.

3) C++ style cast are checked by compiler to make sure whether casting is used in the proper context OR not.

Comment: So is int(t) a C-style cast?

Comment: There being more to read does not make it more readable. It can sometimes clarify what exact cast you want/expect.

Comment: @Robinson It's on the same line as C-style cast... not keeping above points while casting