# GCC 4.2.2 unsigned short error in casting

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer

this line of code isn't compiling for me on GCC 4.2.2

```
m_Pout->m_R[i][j] = MIN(MAX(unsigned short(m_Pin->m_R[i][j]), 0), ((1 << 15) - 1));
```

> error: expected primary-expression before ‘unsigned’

however if I add braces to `(unsigned short)` it works fine.

can you please explain what type of casting (allocation) is being done here?

why isn't the lexical parser/compiler is able to understand this c++ code in GCC?

Can you suggest a "better" way to write this code? supporting GCC 4.2.2 (no c++11, and cross platform)

Comment: GCC 4.2 is a very old compiler (2008). Please upgrade it to a newer version. You could download a newer version  ([GCC 5.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/) in july 2015) and compile it from its source code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch if it was up to me... ohhh if only... :(

Comment: Why can't you compile GCC 5 from it source code? You don't need any root permissions for that (just in the GCC 5 build tree ..`../gcc-5.1/configure --prefix=$HOME/soft --program-suffix=-mine`...) then `make` then `make install`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: The problem is that GCC assumes a glibc version and Linux ships with a glibc version. The two are not necessarily the same and this can cause major problems. On Windows, Microsoft has made it quite explicit that the different MSVCRT versions are not part of the OS, and since 7.0 they're even named differently so they can co-exist.

Comment: If you compile GCC from its source code, it will fit to the glibc you have.

Comment: @MSalters, GCC doesn't assume a glibc version, that's complete nonsense. It probes the C library during the configure step to see what features are present, and adjusts itself accordingly.

Comment: I'm curious... How can people have managers forbidding usage of a recent GCC compiler, and forcing them to use an obsolete one, like the comments above are implicitly suggesting? [Peter principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Principle) ?

Comment: Well sometimes it means a very long delay in an already working system.  Which juat doesn't worth the trouble.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Which includes the assumption that it will be compiling for the host environment. If you compile on the same machine as where you run the executable, then yes there's only one glibc and the assumption is valid. But when I build an executable on my desktop so the field engineers can put it on servers in the field, it's a bloody annoying complication.

Comment: @MSalters, no, it doesn't assume compiling for the host environment, because you configure against the target glibc. If you're configuring against the wrong environment then you're doing it wrong. If the OP already has a working compiler then they already have either a native or cross-glibc in place, and so could use the same one when building a new GCC.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, upgrading the compiler might mean rebuilding and retesting large numbers of third-party libraries, including fixing anything that breaks (C++ code written for GCC 4.2 is very unlikely to compile cleanly with recent releases). It might be a lot of work to revalidate everything, so needs to be coordinated and planned not just done blithely. Of course the more often you do it the easier each upgrade is likely to be ... going from 4.2 to 5.1 is a big jump.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: And if you don't pass any special option, the default (aka assumption) in configuring GCC is the glibc locally installed. It's fixable, yes, but you must explicitly configure GCC to match the target environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Bathsheba's answer is at least misleading. `short(m_Pin->m_R[i][j])` is a cast. Why is it that the extra `unsigned` messing things up? It's because `unsigned short` is not a *simple-type-specifier*. The cast syntax `T(E)` works only if T is a single token, and `unsigned short` is two tokens.

Other types which are spelled with more than one token are `char*` and `int const`, and therefore these are also not valid casts: `char*(0)` and `int const(0)`.

With `static_cast<>`, the `< >` are balanced so the type can be named with a sequence of identifiers, even `static_cast<int const*const>(0)`

Answer (score 4):

1. `unsigned short(m_Pin->m_R[i][j])` is a *declaration* with initialisation of an anonymous temporary, and that cannot be part of an *expression*.
2. `(unsigned short)(m_Pin->m_R[i][j])` is a *cast*, and *is* an expression.

So (1) cannot be used as an argument for `MAX`, but (2) can be.

Comment: but why isn't it working for GCC without the braces?

Comment: @Gilad: Because that's the very syntax of C++. A cast is represented by a typename in parentheses in front of an expression.

Comment: Could you paste up the "with braces" case? I didn't catch it the first time round. Unless you mean brackets?

Comment: @Gilad: It is there ("2.").

Comment: m_Pout->m_R[i][j] = MIN(MAX((unsigned short)(m_Pin->m_R[i][j]), 0), ((1 << 15) - 1));

Comment: @Bathsheba: Technically parentheses ... Braces: `{}`.  Brackets: `[]`.  Parentheses: `()`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the §2 in [Bathsheba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31406978/841108) but it is more [idiomatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103512/in-c-why-use-static-castintx-instead-of-intx) to use `static_cast` in C++:

```
static_cast<unsigned short>(m_Pin->m_R[i][j])
```

<sup>BTW, your error is not related to GCC. You'll get the same if using [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) or any (C++99 or C++11) standard conforming C++ compiler.</sup>

---

But independently of that, you should use a much newer version of GCC. In july 2015 the current version is [GCC 5.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/) and your [GCC 4.2.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.2/) version is from 2007, which is very ancient.

Using a more recent version of GCC is worthwhile because:

- it enables you to stick to a more recent version of C++, e.g. C++11 (compile with `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11`)
- recent GCC have improved their diagnostics. Compiling with `-Wall -Wextra` will help a lot.
- recent GCC are optimizing better, and you'll get more performance from your code
- recent GCC have a better and more standard conforming standard C++ library
- recent GCC are better for debugging (with a recent GDB), and have sanitizer options (`-fsanitize=address`, `-fsanitize=undefined`, other `-fsanitize=`.... options) which help finding bugs
- recent GCC are more standard conforming
- recent GCC are customizable thru plugins, including [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)
- older GCC 4.2 is no more supported by the FSF, and you'll need to pay big bucks the few companies supporting them.

You don't need any root access to compile from its source code a [GCC 5](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/) compiler (or cross-compiler). Read the [installation](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/) procedures. You'll build a GCC tailored to your particular libc (and you might even use [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) if you wanted to ....), perhaps by compiling *outside* of the source tree after having configured with a command like

```
 ...your-path-to/gcc-5/configure --prefix=$HOME/soft/ --program-suffix=-mine
```

then `make` then `make install` then add `$HOME/soft/bin/` to your `PATH` and use `gcc-mine` and `g++-mine`