# How does static casting from long to double in c++ differ from using the double constructor?

Tags: c++

I'm in the habit of doing 1. to coerce the code below into a floating point calculation but it just occurred to me: is there any difference in behaviour with 2.? It certainly looks less neater.

```
long blah = 3;

// 1

double d1 = 1 / static_cast<double>(blah);

// 2 note: not C-style (double) blah

double d2 = 1 / double(blah);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use static\_cast<int>(x) instead of (int)x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103512/why-use-static-castintx-instead-of-intx)

Comment: No, I don't think so. It's not a C-style cast.

Comment: It is, in everything, but name: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast _The functional cast expression [...] is exactly equivalent to the corresponding C-style cast expression._

Comment: Excellent, cheers!

Comment: You can get the same effect without any casts: double d = 1.0 / blah;`.

Comment: Yeah, good idea. This particular bit of code has loads of them so I'm just trying to make it look a little cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

Using a scalar type like a constructor, and the equivalent "C-style" cast syntax, is shorthand for `static_cast`, `const_cast`, and/or `reinterpret_cast`, whichever is needed. Since it's imprecise, it can mask an error.

In this case, and for all conversions between built-in numeric types, the C-style cast is the same as `static_cast`. Still, many C++ users (including me) consider it a bad habit even so.

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast for exact order of casts attempted. C-style casts use the first one of these that is successful.