# Nested static_cast and const_cast

Tags: c++, static-cast, const-cast

I have a system call like the following one:

```
int transfer(int handle, int direction, unsigned char *data, int length);
```

I have written the following two functions:

```
int input(int handle, void* data, int length)
{
    return transfer(handle, 1, static_cast<unsigned char*>(data), length);
}

int output(int handle, const void* data, int length)
{
    return transfer(handle, 0, static_cast<unsigned char*>(const_cast<void*>(data)), length);
}
```

I don't like the nested `const_cast` inside the `static_cast`, is there a way to perform the conversion from `const void*` to `unsigned char*` in a single step?

Comment: That cast sequence being ugly is a feature here, it is dangerous.

Comment: The only c++ cast that can remove `const` is `const_cast`, even `reinterpret_cast` (which lets you try to cast almost anything) won't let you cast away `const`. A single step cast that would work is a C cast. It would resolve to the same (or nearly) series of casts, but it would appear to be a single cast. I would recommend keeping the long series of casts.

Comment: is actually _const correct your_ output function?

Comment: @Moia the system function `transfer` is quite ugly, but it doesn't modify the passed buffer if `direction` is `0` (output).

Comment: Well, reading your comments you have to adapt to something that is not well designed and that you cannot change. I think you have no other way to do, but using C-style cast or copying the `data` into a `unsigned char` buffer that you would pass to `transfer()` instead. You probably don't want to do that.

Comment: const in `const void* data` is only there so that you would not modify `data` inside of your function. But as you cast it away, the funciton signature might just as well be `int output(int handle, void* data, int length)`. Or better `int output(int handle, unsigned char* data, int length)`.

Comment: @JHBonarius the `input` and `output` functions have the proper parameters, they exist for the purpose of hiding the ugly and bad signature of the `transfer` function.

Comment: @Wizard79 but that's only a mirage, as you immediately cast away the `const`. Externally you're just 'tricked' that there's a guarantee that the parameter you pass will not be modified. Like I said in my answer: what if `transfer` would actually modify the value? Then you could potentially have an unexplained data corruption, which could take a long time to debug. I would not cover up this signature by recasting everything, because you're misleading the user. Instead make a copy or so, like I propose in my answer.

Comment: @JHBonarius it's not a mirage, it's a contract. The contract is respected as the buffer passed to `transfer` is not modified if `direction` is 0. `const` itself doesn't translate to any code, it is a contract itself. I think that your suggestion to make a copy is very bad: it has a performance and memory impact for no reason.

Comment: @Wizard79 That might be the case for now, but what if somebody modifies the code of `transfer` (or some comparable function in an similar situation). For instance now reordering the data in `data` for optimal communication: then you suddenly have a change in your original data. So, you might be convinced that you're doing the right thing, but along the way you're making a lot of assumptions. I've been debugging a lot of old code in my career, where designers were making such assumptions that turned up as a bug after x years. `const_cast` can be very dangerous.

Comment: @JHBonarius if and when `transfer` will do something as dumb as modifying the output buffer, `output` will be changed accordingly. By the way, this is what happens inside glibc `write`: `const` qualifier for the passed buffer is silently dropped when passed to `syscall`. You have to trust the contract, the buffer will not be modified inside the kernel for this syscall.

Comment: Even contracts can changed over time. I've seen the bugs... In this case I'd expect the API supplier to provide suitable `transmit` and `receive` interfaces, instead of one ring to rule them all. By the way glibc is not C++. It's not C even, but often implemented in assembly. There's no `const` in assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a C-style cast will generate identical assembly. [As seen in Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/yFpXsk):

```
//Source #1
int transfer(int handle, int direction, unsigned char *data, int length);
int input(int handle, void* data, int length)
{
    return transfer(handle, 1, static_cast<unsigned char*>(data), length);
}

int output(int handle, const void* data, int length)
{
    return transfer(handle, 0, static_cast<unsigned char*>(const_cast<void*>(data)), length);
}

//Source #2
int transfer(int handle, int direction, unsigned char *data, int length);
int input(int handle, void* data, int length)
{
    return transfer(handle, 1, (unsigned char*)data, length);
}

int output(int handle, const void* data, int length)
{
    return transfer(handle, 0, (unsigned char*)data, length);
}

//Assembly (both)
input(int, void*, int):
        mov     ecx, edx
        mov     rdx, rsi
        mov     esi, 1
        jmp     transfer(int, int, unsigned char*, int)
output(int, void const*, int):
        mov     ecx, edx
        mov     rdx, rsi
        xor     esi, esi
        jmp     transfer(int, int, unsigned char*, int)
```

So it's clear that simply using a C-style cast will solve your problem.

## However, you *shouldn't* use a C-style cast

The reason for the verboseness of the C++ casts is to ensure that you aren't making mistakes. When a maintainer sees your code, it's important that they see the `const_cast` and the `static_cast`, because writing the code this way informs the reader that casting away the `const`-ness of the pointer is intentional and desired behavior. A code maintainer should see these casts, and presume that there was intent behind the code, instead of having to guess whether you knew that casting directly from `const void*` to `unsigned char*` would involve risking Undefined Behavior. Your example might not contain UB (since you specified that the contract of `transfer` is to treat `data` as read-only when `direction` is 0), but it's important that anyone else who needs to make changes to your code understands the deliberateness of your coding practices.

Comment: _However, you shouldn't use a C-style cast_ Disagree.  If what you are doing with C++ style casts is effectively the same, then the code will be a lot clearer (and shorter) if you simply code up a C-style cast and be done with it.  If the person reading the code has so little faith in you that he doesn't "trust" you, then there is a deeper problem (and you can always comment the code).

Comment: _The reason for the verboseness of the C++ casts is to ensure that you aren't making mistakes_ No, it is for expressiveness.  The reason for the _different flavours_ of C++ casts is to (try to) ensure that you are not making mistakes. (Welcome to pedantry corner).

Comment: @PaulSanders "Clearer" and "Shorter" are not synonyms in this context. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/103868/5241642) for a more comprehensive rationale for insisting on C++-style casts over C-style casts.

Comment: I don't think I claimed that they were.  And while that is a nice answer you link to there, I don't see it as being pertinent to the OP's specific question (because he is just casting pointers to primitive objects).

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `data` to be un-const'd. What if `transfer` tried to modify it?
It would be safer to have a local copy:

```
#include <cstring>
int output(int handle, const void* data, int length)
{
    unsigned char localData[length];
    std::memcpy(localData, data, length);
    return transfer(handle, 0, localData, length);
}
```

edit: reading through the comments, this is what Shlublu suggested...

Comment: This answer is off topic, the question is "is there a way to perform the conversion from const void* to unsigned char* in a single step?". You are answering to "in this scenario it is correct to cast away const?"

Comment: By the way, there is absolutely nothing wrong in casting away `const` here: `transfer` will not modify the passed buffer if `direction` is 0.

Comment: @Wizard79 SO is full of XY problems. Very often the correct answer to a question is not what the OP asked.