# Error: "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type" while trying to use modulus

Tags: c++

I use VS Code for C++ compiler, while I was trying to find the modulus for calculating how many gallons of paint the user needs, so I created a variable for it, but then it said "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type", how to solve it?

Consider the following:

> -Figure out the size of our room. -Determine the amount of paintable space for a room using variables. -Add variables for unpaintable spaces such as doors and windows. Assume all --other wall space is paintable. -One gallon of paint will cover 400 sq. ft. Write an application that will print the number of square feet that needs to be covered and the number of gallons of paint that you will need. Create a reusable code by using variables for storing values.

If I switch the modulus to divide, then the error will be gone, but that's not what I want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //creating variables
    double space;
    int numberOfWindows;
    int paint = 400;
    int gallonOfPaint;
    double sizeOfWindow;
    double squarefeet = sizeOfWindow * numberOfWindows - space;
    int modulus = squarefeet % paint;

    //getting data
    cout << "Welcome, this is a calulator to calculate how much paint you need." << endl;
    cout << "Enter the square feet of your room: ";
    cin >> space;
    cout << "Enter how many windows you have: ";
    cin >> numberOfWindows;

    //Determine how big the windows is
    if(numberOfWindows > 0){
        cout << "How big is your windows? ";
        cin >> sizeOfWindow;
        //Determine how much paint the user need
        if(modulus > 0.1){
            gallonOfPaint++;
            cout << "You need " << gallonOfPaint << " gallon(s) of paint." << endl;
        } else if(modulus < 0.1){
            int answer = space / paint;
            cout << "You need " << answer << "gallon(s) of paint." << endl;
        }
    } else if(numberOfWindows = 0){
        if(modulus > 0.1){
            gallonOfPaint++;
            cout << "You need " << gallonOfPaint << " gallon(s) of paint." << endl;
        } else if(modulus < 0.1){
            int answer = squarefeet / paint;
            cout << "You need " << answer << "gallon(s) of paint." << endl;
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Error Message: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

Comment: Your program has more grave problems than that. You are using variables without ever initialising them, this is undefined behaviour and makes no sense. Please see [Why enable warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

squarefeet is double. Sometimes that happens - you want to work with double, you understand this is possible, but c++ won't allow you to do this.
But almost always there is other way:

1) Store decimal part somewhere `double decPart = squarefeet - (int)squarefeet;`

2) Use modulus on integer `int intPart = (int)squarefeet % paint;`

3) Calculate `double modulus = decPart + intPart;`

Or use integer typesas other answer suggested.

Comment: I would use static_cast<int> instead of (int) for type safety.

Comment: I see, thanks! but what does (int)squarefeet means? Does it mean that you are changing the data types into int instead of double?

Comment: @FlashSonic526 Yes, this is explicit type conversion. And static_cast<int> ,that was mentioned in previous comment, is almost the same - look here for details - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103512/why-use-static-castintx-instead-of-intx

Comment: An even simpler approach - assuming the need is to work with variables of type `double` (i.e a fractional modulus) - is to use the standard function from `<cmath>` named `fmod()`.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in modulus operator, `%`, may not be used with `double`s. That's what the compiler is letting you know.

```
int modulus = squarefeet % paint;
```

can be used only if `squarefeet` AND `paint` are integral types or unscoped enumeration types. Change `squarefeet` to an `int`.

```
int squarefeet = sizeOfWindow * numberOfWindows - space;
int modulus = squarefeet % paint;
```

to remove that error.