# How to implement classes derived from an abstract with different methods?

Tags: c++, class, oop, methods, abstract-class

I have implemented different classes derived from an abstract class and each one has different methods. The problem is that I have to declare the object only at runtime, so I have to create a pointer to the base class and I can't use the methods of each derived class.

I have created an example to explain better what I mean:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class poligon
{
public:
    double h, l;
    void setPoligon(double h, double l) {
        this->h = h;
        this->l = l;
    }
    virtual double GetArea() = 0;
    virtual void GetType() = 0;
};


class triangle : public poligon
{
    double GetArea() { return l*h / 2; }
    void GetType() { cout << "triangle" << endl; }
    double GetDiag() { return sqrt(l*l + h*h); }
};


class rectangle : public poligon
{
    double GetArea() { return l*h; }
    void GetType() { cout << "rectangle" << endl; }
};


void main()
{
    poligon* X;
    int input;

    cout << "1 for triangle and 2 for rectangle: ";
    cin >> input;

    if (input == 1)
    {
        X = new triangle;
    }
    else if (input == 2)
    {
        X = new rectangle;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error";
    }

    X->h = 5;
    X->l = 6;

    X->GetType();
    cout << "Area = " << X->GetArea() << endl;

    if (input == 2)
    {
        cout << "Diangonal = " << X->GetDiag() << endl;    // NOT POSSIBLE BECAUSE " GetDiag()" IS NOT A METHOD OF "poligon" CLASS !!!
    }
}
```

Obviously the method `X->GetDiag()` at the end of the main can't be used because it is not a method of the "poligon" class.
Which is the correct implementation of a program with this logic?

Comment: Don't bother with runtime polymorphism then. Call different functions based on the user input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Introduce a method in the base class

```
virtual bool boHasDiagonal(void) =0;
```

Declare unconditionally in base class:

```
virtual double GetDiag();
```

Implement it differently in both derived classes:

```
virtual bool boHasDiagonal(void) {return true;} // rectangle
virtual bool boHasDiagonal(void) {return false;} // triangle
```

Change output line:

```
if (X->boHasDiagonal())
{cout << "Diangonal = " << X->GetDiag() << endl;}
```

For a nice touch of paranoia (a healthy state of mind for a programmer in my opinion), use concept by Gluttton of a default implementation of `GetDiag()`, which signals an error (as in his answer here) .

For the case of many poligons, I like the proposal by Rakete1111 in the comment.

Comment: Because only some classes would override `boHasDiagonal` to return `true`, how about providing a default definition for `boHasDiagonal` in `polygon` to return `false`? That would save a lot of typing if you have a lot of polygons that don't have any diagonal.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Nice touch. I imagine GetDiag() could be semantically defined to mean "longest diagonal" and be implemented for precisely half of all poligons, but you are still right. Actually it could be "longest point to point" and be implemented for all, but that would be boring and against OPs intent, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Define method in the base class which define implementation throws exception:

```
class poligon
{
public:
    virtual double GetDiag()
    {
        throw std::logic_error ("Called function with inappropriate default implementation.");
    }
};
```

In class that has meaningful implementation override it:

```
class rectangle : public poligon
{
    double GetDiag() override
    {
        return diagonale;
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
int main () {
    try {
        X->GetDiag();
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << "Looks like polygon doesn't have diagonal." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dynamic_cast`.

```
dynamic_cast<triangle*>(X)->GetDiag();
```

Note that you already have a bug: You only create a `triangle` if `input == 1`, but you get the diagonal if `input == 2`. Also, the above is not really safe, because `dynamic_cast` can return `nullptr` if the conversion is invalid.

But it would be better to check whether `dynamic_cast` succeeds, then you could also drop the `input == 2` check:

```
if (triangle* tri = dynamic_cast<triangle*>(X))
    std::cout << "Diagonal = " << tri->GetDiag() << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `dynamic_cast` to access subclass-methods.
It returns `nullptr` if it is not derived from the class. This is called **down cast**, as you are going down the class-tree:

```
triangle* R = dynamic_cast<triangle*>(X);
if(R) {
    cout << "Diagonale = " << R->GetDiag() << '\n';
};
```

**Edit:** You can put the declaration in the first line into the if-condition, which goes out of scope outside the if-statement:

```
if(triangle* R = dynamic_cast<triangle*>(X)) {
    cout << "Diagonale = " << R->GetDiag() << '\n';
};

if(rectangle* R = ...) {...}; // reuse of identifier
```

---

If you want to allow, that `multiple subclasses` have the `GetDiag` function you can inherit from the `poligon`-class and another `diagonal`-class. The `diagonal`-class only defines the `GetDiag` function and has not really to do with the `polygon`-class:

```
class polygon {
    // stays the same
};

class diagonal {
    virtual double GetDiag() = 0;
};

class triangle : public polygon, public diagonal {
    // body stays the same
};
```

And like above, you access the methods via casting with `dynamic_cast` but this time you cast to type `diagonal`. This time it is **side cast**, because `poligon` has nothing to do with `diagonal`, so you are going sideways in the tree.

```
   polygon         diagonal
    |   |             |
    |   |_____________|
    |          |
    |          |
rectangle   triangle
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [dynamic casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781763/what-exactly-is-dynamic-casting-in-c) to check if the base class' pointer is actually a triangle, like this:

```
int main()
{
    ...
    if(triangle* t = dynamic_cast<triangle*>(X))
        std::cout << "Triangle's diagonal = " << t->GetDiag() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

PS: I assume that your example is just a draft, since it has some bugs.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can use `dynamic_cast` to change the static type in your program, add a method to the base-class with a pseudo implementation or use some form of type-switching. However, I would consider all these answers as signs of a design flaw in your program and would reject the code. They all encode assumptions about the types existing in your program into the code and pose a maintenance burden. Imagine adding new types of shapes to your program. You then have to search and modify all the places you `dynamic_cast` your objects.

I think your example hierarchy is wrong in the first place. When you declare a base-class for ploygons, and derive triangles from it, the whole purpose of polymorphism is to be able to treat similar objects identically. So anything that is not common behavior (*not implementation*) is put in the base-class.

```
class poligon
{
public:
    double h, l;
    void setPoligon(double h, double l) {
        this->h = h;
        this->l = l;
    }
    virtual double GetArea() = 0;
    virtual void GetType() = 0;
};


class triangle : public poligon
{
    double GetArea() { return l*h / 2; }
    void GetType() { cout << "triangle" << endl; }
    double GetDiag() { return sqrt(l*l + h*h); }
};
```

You explicitly say that I can replace any instance of polygon with an instance of triangle everywhere in your program. This is the the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). What about circles? They don't have height and length. Can you use a rectangle everywhere you expect a polygon? Currently you can, but polygons can have more edges, be self-intersecting etc. I cannot add a new edge to a rectangle, otherwise it would be a rectangle anymore.

There are some solutions, but as it is a design question, the solution depends on what you want to do with the objects.

Answer (score 0):

A downcast is usually a sign of a bad design and is rarely needed in practice.

I can't see why it is needed in this particular case. You have discarded the information about which type you have for no reason. An alternative could be:

```
void printDiagonal(const triangle& tri)
{
    std::cout << "Diangonal = " << tri.GetDiag() << std::endl;
}

void process(poligon& p)
{
    p.h = 5;
    p.l = 6;

    p.GetType();
    std::cout << "Area = " << p.GetArea() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int input;

    std::cout << "1 for triangle and 2 for rectangle: ";
    std::cin >> input;

    if (input == 1)
    {
        triangle tri;
        process(tri);
        printDiagonal(tri);
    }
    else if (input == 2)
    {
        rectangle rect;
        process(rect);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error\n";
    }
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rcrIItbAYpaVXX2N).