# Chaning datatype of a variable (loginID) from integer to long or string in a million lines of code

Tags: java, string, design-patterns, int, long-integer

I am working with a big software (million lines code) written in java. It is accessed with a field loginID of type integer (4 bytes ~ 10 digits). Now we are running out of this value as the loginID value crossing 10digits ( 2147483647) in near future. loginID is being used in almost every classes as integer only. But in our Database we have been storing this loginID as long (22 digits length).  Now I we want to refactor the software code by changing the loginID from  int to long/string.

Suggest me a way how to make this change peacefully.

Comment: Sounds like a piece of boring work... But at least the compiler will let you know the places you missed.

Comment: this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617039/how-to-dynamically-cast-an-instance-of-object-type-into-its-specific-data-type

Comment: @Thilo: Compiler will throw error but changing at thousands of places manually is really an hectic job. How to detect all those places which are error prone due to loginID change from int to long/string. And the software has many separate modules.