# C#, Generic Items list, with Specific Items in it

Tags: c#

Say I have three classes that look like this:

```
abstract class Fruit
{
     public string name { get; set; }
}

class Apple : Fruit
{
     public int redness { get; set; }
}

class Pear : Fruit
{
     public int size { get; set; }
}
```

And somewhere else I have:

```
List<Fruit> delicious_things = new List<Fruit>{
      new Pear(){}
      new Apple(){}
}
```

How do I access, as an example the pear.size from delicious_things?

If I know already that Pear is delicious_things[0], I could do: delicious_things[0].size, but that doesn't seem to work.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider interfaces and unification around such (or, since there is subtyping, around the base type) - I would argue that different types of fruit probably all have "color" and "size" characteristics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to access specific properties you need to perform a cast.Also you should consider using [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) or [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) operators when performing casts.Because if you try to perform a cast from one incompatible type to another (for ex. from `Apple` to `Pear`) you will get an `InvalidCastException`:

```
var pear = delicious_things[0] as Pear;
int size;
if(pear != null) size = pear.size;
```

Or:

```
if(delicious_things[0] is Pear)
{
   int size = ((Pear)delicious_things[0]).size; 
}
```

Comment: this appears to be the only answer that doesn't blow up if you don't have a pear

Comment: @failedprogramming - I think that is because the question asked `If I know already that Pear is delicious_things[0]`

Comment: @Oren regardless of how the question was asked, it does not change the fact that this answer can handle a no pear situation. While your answer fits within the parameters of this question, I'm just saying I personally prefer this one as it can achieve more. No disrespect intended.

Comment: @failedprogramming - Agreed - Probably more educational for a beginner to see the use of the `as` and `is` operators.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to cast the item to the specific type.

```
((Pear)delicious_things[0]).size
```

However, this is not good design. See [Why should casting be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167304/why-should-casting-be-avoided)

Comment: Thanks!

As a followup: Can I somehow see the type/class of [0] in that list?

Comment: You can set a debug point and inspect `delicious_things` and it will show you the concrete types of each item.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without debugging?

Comment: You should probably rethink your design. If you are constantly downcasting your items.. you've done something wrong. Code shouldn't be littered with casts like this everywhere.

Comment: Using the `GetType()` method. Though as mentioned, if you are thinking about doing it this way, you're probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

what you can do to filter for a specific type is:

```
delicious_things.OfType<Pear>().First().size;
```

like that you are sure its gonna take the first `Pear` without casting the objects.

Of course you are still not sure if the list contains at least one element of type `Pear`

think always about all possibilities --> otherwise once in the future you will fall over it