# How Objects stored in memory? Inherting a Base Class vs. Creating a Base Class Member Object

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

```
class Base
{
public:
    int nX;
    int nY;
    Base(){};
    ~Base(){};
};

class Derived
{
private:
    Base pBase;
    int mX;
    int mY;
public:
    Derived(){}
    Derived(int x , int y) { pBase.nX = x; pBase.nY = y;}
    ~Derived(){}
    void Print()
    {
        std::cout<<"Base X is "<< pBase.nX << ", Base Y is " << pBase.nY << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Derived pDerived(10,9);
    Base* pBase = reinterpret_cast<Base*>(&pDerived);
    pDerived.Print();
    std::cout<<"Cast X is "<< pBase->nX<<", Cast Y is "<< pBase->nY<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have come across something above in a Source which did not inherit a Base Class, yet Include it as part of the class/struct, sent to another consumer function as a *base pointer*, then using `reinterpret_cast` to cast it back to the Derived class(or another) Depending on the value of `nX`.

`nX` is **Guaranteed** to be unique for every class, At least from what I can see from the source.

I've oversimplified it's usage for the code, and I'm Calling it as `Base` and `Derived` due to the lack of a better term since *I have absolutely no idea what to call this practice*.

The code does seem to grab the proper address, and does output the correct values for `nX` and `nY`, and the Applications logic does work as well. The classes doesn't have any `virtual` functions except for a Default Constructor, unlike my example. I have also kept the `structure` of the class in my sample, with the *member variables* above the constructors/member Functions.

My question is, How are objects Stored in memory either automatically or dynamically, Are guaranteed to behave this way(*Stored Similar to Structs* as stated [on an answer on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405112/how-are-objects-stored-in-memory-in-c), given the Code above.)? or is this an *undefined behavior*, and not fixing this would eventually run into *segmentation faults* or *Access Violations*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is cast a pointer points-to-class to it's first member illegal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49333703/is-cast-a-pointer-points-to-class-to-its-first-member-illegal)

Comment: @appleapple I have read that thread, I posted question since I haven't got the faintest Idea what the Practice is called and The thread's sample was for _dynamic_ objects and I wasn't sure if it would still be the case for automatic objects, Specially on VS2008.

Comment: @‌AzrielElijay pointer-interconvertibility has nothing to do with (automatic/dynamic) storage duration.

Comment: I have no idea about  what VS2008 would do or if it has any bug, fwiw.

Answer (score 0):

The codes uses *composition* not *inheritance* when it keeps an instance of another class as its member. The `reinterpret` cast only works if the member `pBase` is the first member.

Once you add another member in front of it, your code will have UB, see example: https://www.godbolt.org/z/3ocr9q5Ts

For more details see [is cast a pointer points-to-class to it's first member illegal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49333703/is-cast-a-pointer-points-to-class-to-its-first-member-illegal)