# Are there differences between explicit type conversion "operators" in case of basic types?

Tags: c++

Simple thing: I would like to "convert" e.g. a `float` into a `double`. Now there are three ways known to me:

```
float v = 4.2f;
```

1. `double u = (double)v;`
2. `double u = double(v);`
3. `double u = static_cast<double>(v);`
4. `double u(v);` **Edit: Just thought about this as a fourth option!**

Are these identical or are there any subtle differences? What do you suggest to use?

Note that this question is only related to basic types like int, char, float, ... not to pointers, PODs or classes.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast/1255015#1255015

Comment: @icecrime: Your link handles conversion for pointers to polymorphic classes - not basic types.

Comment: A `float` is automatically converted into a `double` just by `double d = f;`. No need to worry. A conversion that loses precision must be handled much more carefully though, and I guess it depends on the specific application. Syntactically though, I would recommend `static_cast` simply because it later allows you to search for `_cast` to find all your casts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`double u = (double)v;` and `double u = static_cast<double>(v);` are equivalent  because for both cases a standard conversion is used. However `double u = double(v);` creates a temporary double object (which can be optimized away anyway) which is then used to initialize `u`. But since a temporaty is created anyway, using all three kinds of casts, then yeah, it's the same.

From the three `static_cast` should be preferred. It's a couple of characters more typing, but in the long run it's better because first of all you explicitly specify the cast type and also since casting is generally suspicious, you do it in a very vivid manner

Comment: They are equivalent **in this case**, yet `static_cast<double>` should be preferred !

Comment: @icecrime: OK, I gave it a bit thought, and yes, they are equivlent :)

Comment: @Armen, you should edit to add that static_cast<> is much prefered over C-style cast.

Comment: @Armen: The cast type is explicitly specified in all three versions - thats the point of explicit casts ;)

Comment: `(double)v` and `double(v)` both are totally equivalent. Notice that `double(v)` and `(double)v` are said to create temporaries in the current IS, but that's a defect (there will be no temporary: A temporary is an object with a certain limited lifetime, but for `double(v)` there won't be an object created (there will if you try binding it to a const reference)). See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#943 .

Comment: @Johannes: Mind posting your comment as an answer and noting something about the 4-th case? The answer of Armen is not satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

What about `double u = v;` and let the compiler do its default promotion from `float` to `double`?

If you want to explicitly show the conversion the `static_cast` is the preferred C++ way to do it. It's more typing but it tells the compiler precisely which conversion you want to happen.

Comment: Not using an explicit cast in case of float -> double or other casts which (may) loose information will generate a compiler warning!

Comment: @Danvil How could `float` -> `double` lose information? `double` is guaranteed to be at least as big as `float`