# Do polymorphic C-style casts have any overhead?

Tags: c++, casting, polymorphism

- Does casting a pointer to an instance of a dervived class to the instances base class have any run-time overhead in C++, or is it resolved at compile-time?
- If it does have any, what exactly has to be computed in the casting operation?

Example:

```
class Foo;
class Bar : public Foo;

Bar* y = new Bar;
Foo* x = (Foo*) y;
```

*(I know I should use C++-style casts and that the answer is probably the same for them)*

Answer (score 6):

Yes, though it's negligible.

In this case, a C-Style cast is interpreted as a `static_cast`, which may incur a pointer adjustment.

```
struct Base {};

struct Derived: Base { virtual ~Derived(); } // note: introduced a virtual method

int main()
{
  Derived derived;
  Base* b = &derived;
  Derived* d = (Derived*) b;

  void* pb = b;
  void* pd = d;

  printf("%p %p", pb, pd);

  return 0;
}
```

This overhead happens whenever the base subobject is not aligned at the same address that the derived object, which happens when:

- introducing the first virtual method
- using multi-inheritance

Of course, pointer adjustment is usually counted as negligible, and the compiler shall be smart enough to eliminate it if it's unnecessary anyway (an adjustment of 0).

*Note: this is implementation dependent, not mandated by the standard*

Answer (score 5):

```
Foo* x = (Foo*) y;
```

You don't need to cast `Bar*` to `Foo*`. Casting from Derived to Base is implicit:

```
Foo* x = y ; // is enough!
```

As for polymorphic cast, C-style cast is not equivalent to `dynamic_cast`. C++ `dynamic_cast` is completely a new feature added to the language, and has no match in C-style cast.

> Does casting a pointer to an instance
>   of a dervived class to the instances
>   base class have any run-time overhead
>   in C++, or is it resolved at
>   compile-time?

Casting from derived to base is resolved at compile-time, if you do as I did above. So it has not runtime overhead.

Comment: This should really be a comment.  Whilst true, it doesn't really address the question...

Comment: @Nawaz: base to derive is only resolved as compile-time cast as far as a `static_cast` is enough. In case of virtual bases a `dynamic_cast` is required.

Comment: @Matthieu : Actually there was a typo. I meant "derived to base". I fixed that.

Comment: @Nawaz: ah okay :) Anyway I would say there could be a slight overhead: pointer adjustment. The offset would be known at compile-time though...

Comment: @Matthieu : We're talking about "runtime" overhead. not compile-time. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes, and a non-null offset implies a runtime computation (a simple addition/substraction... but still!)

Comment: @Matthieu : What are you talking about?

Comment: C doesn't need dynamic cast, it doesn't have classes and structs can't derive from other structs.

Comment: @CashCow: I didn't say C needs dynamic cast. We're talking about C-style cast in C++.

Comment: @Nawaz: look at my example, the base subobject is not necessarily aligned at the same address than the full object, in which case the pointer need be adjusted when casting.

Comment: @Matthieu : need to be adjusted at compile-time or runtime?

Answer (score 3):

C casts have no runtime overhead whatsoever. The only cast operation which creates runtime overhead is `dynamic_cast<>()` as it checks runtime type information.

Comment: Are you sure this (i.e. "no runtime overhead") is true even in the case of multiple inheritance?

Comment: @Oli:  Yes, since only `dynamic_cast` can cast _across_ a multiple inheritance class lattice.  `static_cast` can only cast up and down the lattice.

Comment: @James: I very rarely (i.e. basically never) use MI.  Are you saying that if `C` derives from `A` and `B`, you can't do e.g. `A *p = new C;`?

Comment: @Oli:  No, you can do that:  you can convert from a `Derived*` to a `Base*` (if the base class is accessible, at least).  That conversion only casts up the inheritance lattice.  You can't do `A* p; B* q = static_cast<B*>(p);` because that would cast _across_ the lattice.  You would have to use a pair of `static_cast` casts to convert the `A*` to a `C*` to a `B*`.

Comment: @James: That's what I thought!  Then I think my (implied) original point still stands:  Up-casting in multiple inheritance requires a small amount of pointer arithmetic, and so isn't zero overhead.

Comment: @Oli:  Oh, well, yes, it depends on the definition of "overhead."  By that definition, even `int i = 42; (double)i;` has overhead because the CPU has to convert an `int` to a `double`.  I think the usual meaning of "runtime overhead" when discussing casts is "requires some kind of type lookup."

Answer (score 1):

See the answer to a similar question: [regular cast vs static cast vs dynamic cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast)

Summarized: a C-style cast has no run-time overhead as it tries a bunch of C++ casting methods except `dynamic_cast` (which incurs a run-time penalty).

Comment: Your answer stands in direct conflict with most of the other ones, can you maybe clear up what you mean?

Comment: Made a mistake, sorry :) Corrected my answer.