# printing percentage in c++

Tags: c++, percentage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ int float problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456801/c-int-float-problem)

I'm simply trying to calculate and print a percentage, and although the variables being used in calculation are displaying correctly, the final percentage keeps showing as "0". Here is the code:

```
 int iWageredTot = iBet * 4 * iGames;
    cout<<"Total Won: "<<iBankRoll<<endl;
    cout<<"Wagered total: "<<iWageredTot<<endl;
    float iPercent;
    iPercent = iBankRoll / iWageredTot;
    cout<<iPercent<<"% edge\n"<<endl;
```

And this is the output:

```
Total won: -770
Wagered Total: 4000
0% edge
```

I tried using int, float, and double. What am I missing? Thank you for any help.

Comment: There are tons of other duplicates, I just picked one of the first I found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe

```
iPercent = (float)iBankRoll / iWageredTot;
```

If `iBankRoll` and `iWageredTot` are declared as `int`, `iBankRoll / iWageredTot` will also be an `int` which will be then converted to `float`, but if it's initially `0`, you'll end up with a `float` 0.

Comment: And maybe he should be using `double` rather than `float`.  (`double` is the default floating point type in C++.  While it's not an error to use `float`, it sends the wrong message to the reader, since `float` is normally only used when there is a special reason not to use `double`.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert one of the operands of `/` to a floating point type, otherwise integer division will be performed. You also are only calculating a fraction at the moment. If you want a percentage, you need to multiply by 100.

```
iPercent = (static_cast<float>(iBankRoll) / iWageredTot) * 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are performing (what looks like) integer division, and then assigning the result of that operation to a float.  That's why the float is zero.

To correct this, do floating-point arithmetic instead:

```
iPercent = (float)iBankRoll/(float)iWageredTot;
```