# c++ explicit type cast gives wrong answer

Tags: c++, scope, explicit-conversion

Why would I be getting an int conversion to float wrong in c++? At a point in a program I am explicitly converting an integer with value 10 or 14 to float, and I get 0. Why would that be ? I tried static_cast, gives me same result. Since both int and float are 4 bytes, I am thinking int to float conversion is not a demotion or promotion by size ? Is it related to rounding errors etc ? Can someone please explain.

Here is the code( There is an alteration here which works fine, but I still don't know why) ---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int n;
int sum;

cout << "Please enter the number:";
cin >> n;

int *elements = new int[n];

cout << "Please enter the elements:";
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
   cin >> elements[i];
}
cout << endl;

///// this approach, gives the sum right, but float(sum) fails and always gives zero.

for(int i=0, sum=0; i < n; i++)
{
   sum = sum + elements[i];
}

////// This works, when sum is initialised outside of for loop. float(sum) does the right conversion as well.
//sum = 0;
//for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
//{
//   sum = sum + elements[i];
//}

cout << " float n is " << float(n) << " float sum is "<< float(sum) << endl;
// float(sum) is zero, when sum is initialised from within for loop.

delete[] elements;

return 0;
}
```

command to compile -> g++ 3.2.cpp -o 3.2

Inputs: n = 4; elements = 1 2 3 4

It feels like something minor that I am overlooking.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: We can't explain unless you actually show us what you're describing.

Comment: [possible duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456801/c-int-float-casting)

Comment: Noone can tell what happens without seeing the code.

Comment: In the duplicate question, ints are not converted to float for the operation. In this case, I am getting wrong answer after conversion.

Comment: [Seems to work fine for me](http://ideone.com/3CY8a3) (notice stdout at the bottom says `float n is 2 float sum is 24`).

Comment: [**It works fine**](http://ideone.com/YBnDBg). That code outputs 4 and 10, as it ought to.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble but the problem was this --> When sum is initialised with the for loop(for addition) counter i, like this for(int i=0, sum=0; i<n; i++), I do get the sum right, but float(sum) is zero. Why is this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two different `sum` variables. The `sum` you're initializing in the `for` loop is actually scoped to the for loop, just like the `i` counter. When you do `for (int i = 0, sum = 0; ...` you're creating two new variables, `i` and `sum`, for the loop. Thus, the `sum` variable you're updating in the for-loop is *not* the `sum` variable you think it is (it's shadowing the `sum` variable you want).

This is why it's important to post your real, actual code from the start. Little details like this matter a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your program is with the scope of your `sum variable(s)`. Note that in its present form your program has `two instances of the sum variable`.

One of the `sum` variables is inside your for loop.

`for(int i=0, sum=0; i < n; i++)
{
   sum = sum + elements[i];
}`

Inside the for loop it has a `local scope`, meaning that the sum variable exists only for the duration of the for loop. Outside the for loop it does not exist!

Whereas, in this line of your code `cout << " float n is " << float(n) << " float sum is "<< float(sum) << endl;` the sum variable that you are trying to output is the one declared at the beginning of your program as `int sum;` which is also the `second instance` of the `sum variable` and it *has not been initialized or assigned a value*.
This is what your problem is. 
How can the compiler cast your `int sum` into a `float sum` and output it onto the screen when it has no value assigned to it?

The program works fine as you say for yourself when `sum` is initialized outside the for loop. This is because in this case the `sum` variable used is the one declared at the top (after `int n`). This version of the `sum` variable has a `global scope` for the duration of the whole code body, and when you output it in the end the compiler recognizes the sum as having been initialized to `zero` and incremented inside the for loop.

So the output is the sum of all the numbers inside the array `elements[i]`.

> Remember that the lifetime or scope of a local variable is just within
>   a procedure or a code block whereas the scope of a global variable is
>   throughout the program, meaning it is recognized wherever it is used
>   or referenced.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing division, integer divison truncates. What you can do instead is do the division using floats first, then display using ints. For example, `static_cast<float>(10/14)` will have no effect because the result of `10/14` is `0`, and you're converting `0` to float, which is still `0`. If you are attempting to store the result in an int, it will be zero because of truncation.