# Is RTTI (Run Time Type Information) used in static casting?

Tags: c++, oop, casting, rtti

In OOP concept, is the RTTI (Run Time Type Information) is also used for static casting or it is used only for dynamic casting?

If it is specific for dynamic casting then justify your answer and also please explain why no RTTI for static_casting.

Whats the point in using RTTI for downcasting?

Comment: The FAQ explains [how to accept answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A static cast is a compile-time construct, whereas RTTI is a run-time phenomenon. This means that no, RTTI is not used for `static_cast`.

I suggest you read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast) as it has a lot of great info.

Comment: Use `static_cast` when you *know* the run-time type, `dynamic_cast` otherwise. You don't really have a choice.

Answer (score 1):

`static_cast` does no run-time checking, so presumably it requires no RTTI to be present.  (Of course, this is implementation-dependent.)

`dynamic_cast` *does* do a run-time check (and therefore requires some form of RTTI under-the-hood), which gives you a chance to deal with an incorrect cast!

Comment: **Presumably**? Is it not **Guaranteed** to be a compile time phenomenon?

Comment: @Als No, although that is clearly the intent.  Never the less, lying to the compiler in a `static_cast` is undefined behavior, and anything the compiler does, including causing an immediate crash, is legal.

Comment: @James: No I did not mean, lying to the compiler in `static_cast`, but in any case doing so should just result in an compiler error rather than an runtime UB? Also, my real Q was, `static_cast` is guaranteed to work with only compile time information and not use any runtime information at all?

Comment: @Als No.  With `static_cast`, the compiler trusts you; it isn't required to do any runtime checking, and the intent is that it not do such checking.  If the `static_cast` is a lie---if the object actually pointed to doesn't have the type claimed---then the results are undefined behavior.  (I'm only talking about pointer conversions here.  Things like `static_cast<double>` of an `int` are a different matter.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the trick, if you have some classes like A,B,C,D,E, and they have a common baseclass Base, then a downcast from Base needs to choose correct class. The casting only works if the original object was created to have the same class. In the example with 5 derived classes and one Base class, there is 1:5 chance of getting it right. Which is not very good, and programmers often choose it wrong. static_cast cannot detect the problem at all and wrong choice of the type in static_cast results in crashes. dynamic_cast can detect it, but only in runtime, i.e. dynamic_cast can also fail and return NULL or throw an exception. RTTI is needed so that dynamic_cast can fail properly.