# For loop writing special signs

Tags: c++, char

```
void printchars()
{
  for (x=128;x<224;x++)
      write(x);
```

I want the x to be a char in the write function. How can i change the x to be treated by the write functions as a char, but an int in the loop?

Comment: the whole point of this was to see, whicch char num corresponds to which symbol, so i can insert those in my pictures for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the point of making `x` an `int` if you're just going to strip away its range? That's what makes this a very strange request. You should just make `x` a `unsigned char` -- `for(unsigned char x = 128; x <224; ++ x) { ...`.

If you just want to ensure you're calling the `unsigned char` template specialization of `write<>`, then call it like this:

`write<unsigned char>(x);`

If not, then you will have to use type casting:

`write((unsigned char)x);`

*Edit*: I just realized what you might be experiencing. My guess is that you originally used `char` but found something wrong with numbers over 127. You should probably be using `unsigned char` for `x` instead of either `int` or `char`. I edited my answer to accommodate this. `char` has a range of -128 to +127. `unsigned char` has a range of 0-255.

Comment: C-style type casting is not recommended. static_cast can do the job here.

Comment: In cases like this it really doesn't matter. Purists prefer `static_cast` here but realists use whatever works when you're making a fundamentally unsafe cast.

Comment: Better to learn the right thing than to learn when you can do the wrong thing "safely".

Comment: C++ has safer casts. No reason to use C's dangerous "make it work" cast. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast

Comment: Although I just noticed the top answerer admits he uses C-style casts for numerical casts. Personally, I see no place in C++ for C casts.

Comment: Every construct in C++ is potentially unsafe. It's judging the situation at hand that removes the "potentially" from this decision. I am not saying one should never use C++ casts, I'm saying C-style casts are fine in this case. Go ahead and use `static_cast`, that's great, but don't pretend that `(char)` here is any less safe.

Answer (score 1):

Cast x to a char:

```
write(static_cast<char>(x));
```

Note that it is ok for x to be a char as the loop counter as well.