# Invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘unsigned char*’

Tags: c++, void-pointers, unsigned-char

I have the following code;

```
void* buffer = operator new(100);
unsigned char* etherhead = buffer;
```

I'm getting the following error for that line when trying to compile;

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘unsigned char*’
```

Why do I get that error, I thought a void was "type-less" so it can point at anything, or anything can point to it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to cast as you can not convert a void* to anything without casting it first.

You would need to do

```
unsigned char* etherhead = (unsigned char*)buffer;
```

(although you could use a `static_cast` also)

To learn more about void pointers, take a look at [6.13 — Void pointers](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/613-void-pointers/).

---

The "type-less" state of `void*` only exist in C, not C++ with stronger type-safety.

Answer (score 5):

A `void*` might point at anything and you can convert a pointer to anything else to a `void*` without a cast but you have to use a `static_cast` to do the reverse.

```
unsigned char* etherhead = static_cast<unsigned char*>(buffer);
```

If you want a dynamically allocated buffer of 100 `unsigned char` you are better off doing this and avoiding the cast.

```
unsigned char* p = new unsigned char[100];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can convert any pointer to a void *, but you can't convert void * to anything else without a cast. It might help to imagine that "void" is the base class for EVERYTHING, and "int" and "char" and whatnot are all subclasses of "void."

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bit of lateral thinking: Whenever you think you need casts or pointers, think again. If all you need is 100 unsigned bytes of memory, use

```
std::array<unsigned char, 100> data;
```

or

```
unsigned char data[100];
```

If the size is not constant, use a vector:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> data(size);
```

Raw pointers, the `new` operator, and casts are unsafe, hard to get right and make your program harder to understand. Avoid them if possible.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is designed to be more type safe than C. If this is C code, it may be OK, but also depends on what compiler you are using right now.

Also, technically, "extern "C" int *" and "int *" are different types... (like solaris compiler will pick this out)

I would suggest you using C++ style cast instead of C cast. There are more descriptions here:

[Regular cast vs. static_cast vs. dynamic_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast).

Answer (score 0):

```
void *pt; 

pt=(void*)&i; 
pt=(void*)&dbl;
```

Here's how I would do it.

Comment: Oh :( I thought you could, I though you could allocate X bytes in memory for later use, because a 10 byte char or a 10 byte int are both 10 bytes long, irrelevant of the values of the alloted 10 bytes. Is this wrong?

Comment: Is there a compelling reason you want to re-use the memory? If not, then don't do it, it makes the program unnecessarily complex.