# Error during Curl installation - Detailed steps below

Tags: curl, compiler-errors, installation, solaris

Below are the steps I am trying to get curl installed on a solaris 9 box

steps which I followed :

```
1.take the new tar file.
2.untar it(tar -xvf curl-7.15.0.tar)
3.go to the curl location (cd /home/NYIMSDEV/Curl)
4.run the configuration commands
5.CPPFLAGS="-I/db/pub/infra/DBssl/current/include" LDFLAGS="-R/db/pub/infra/DBssl/current/lib" CC=/db/pub/infra/SUNWspro/current/SUNWspro/bin/CC ./configure --with-ssl=/db/pub/infra/DBssl/current --prefix=/home/NYIMSDEV/Curl 
6. i faced error "ar" file not found in path.
7.added ar path in PATH.(PATH=$PATH:/usr/ccs/bin)
8.another issue faced is .it was not supporting HTTPS protocall.so find the location of openssl and added in command as added in above command (--with-ssl==/db/pub/infra/DBssl/current)
9.after configuration run the make command.
```

But the make failed with the below error to which I am not able to make any sense

```
bash-2.03$ make
Making all in lib
make  all-am
source='base64.c' object='base64.lo' libtool=yes \
DEPDIR=.deps depmode=none /bin/bash ../depcomp \
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile /db/pub/infra/SUNWspro/current/SUNWspro/bin/CC -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I../include -I../lib -I../lib  -I/db/pub/infra/DBssl/current/include -I/db/pub/infra/DBssl/current/include/openssl -I/db/pub/infra/DBssl/current/include   -g -c -o base64.lo base64.c
/db/pub/infra/SUNWspro/current/SUNWspro/bin/CC -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../include -I../lib -I../lib -I/db/pub/infra/DBssl/current/include -I/db/pub/infra/DBssl/current/include/openssl -I/db/pub/infra/DBssl/current/include -g -c base64.c  -KPIC -DPIC -o .libs/base64.o
"base64.c", line 112: Error: Cannot assign void* to unsigned char*.
"base64.c", line 113: Warning: The variable newstr has not yet been assigned a value.
1 Error(s) and 1 Warning(s) detected.
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `base64.lo'
Current working directory /home/NYIMSDEV/Module/curl-7.15.0/lib
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `all'
Current working directory /home/NYIMSDEV/Module/curl-7.15.0/lib
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `all-recursive'
```

Any insight on the error or what is causing it would be a great help

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a C++ compiler to compile C.

[In C++, you can not assign `void *` to a non-`void *` pointer without a proper type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157252/invalid-conversion-from-void-to-unsigned-char).

This is not correct:

```
CC=/db/pub/infra/SUNWspro/current/SUNWspro/bin/CC
```

`CC` (upper case) is for the Solaris Studio C++ compiler.  You want

```
CC=/db/pub/infra/SUNWspro/current/SUNWspro/bin/cc
```

(lower case `cc`) to get the C compiler.