# Avoiding cast when using CImage

Tags: c++, casting

Recently I have seen a few people telling others that if they need to cast they are doing something wrong. I have this code in C++

```
byte* pixel = (byte*)image->GetBits();
```

Here I cast to a `byte*` because GetBits() returns a `void*`. So how would I either

- have `pixel` hold a byte* without casting
- use `void*` (I have never used this type before)

To clarify, I then go on to use `pixel` similar to this.

```
*(pixel) += 20;
*(pixel + 1) += 20;
*(pixel + 2) += 20;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, casting is justified, but in C++, a better way to cast is to use one of the C++-style cast, so here you can use `static_cast` as:

```
byte* pixels = static_cast<byte*>(image->GetBits());
```

To learn about various C++-style cast, and where to use which, read these topics:

- [When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)
- [Regular cast vs. static_cast vs. dynamic_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you explain the difference between a 'normal' cast and a static_cast?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: Edited my answer with some really good links.

Answer (score 2):

Using `void *` without a cast is impossible by definition, since a `void *` cannot be dereferenced/incremented/whatever. It just means "here's a pointer to some data, I don't know what kind".

`GetBits()` returns a `void *` because the best way to access the data depends on the kind of image (in particular from the color depth) and of elaboration you want to do; naturally you have to cast it to something to do something on such data.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is clear. Casting doesn't always mean you're doing something wrong, but it's a code smell.

In your particular case, the code smell is returning a `void *`. Why do you need a function that returns `void *`?

Comment: I don't define the function, it's part of the api of CImage, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx1ex9b5(v=vs.80).aspx.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko so then MS did something wrong. :) Wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I don't know, there's no type that would be really correct for that return value.

Comment: @MatteoItalia maybe a new type? I'm sure there are equivalents in, Java or C# that don't return void*... So a different design could have been made.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, your probably right that equivalents exist in other languages, but they will include type checking, making them slower than c++'s implementation.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko I totally agree. When it comes to C++, there's a point when you reach a trade-off between a good design and something fast. A bloated design will probably decrease speed. But I thought that was the question, right? I was rash to say MS was wrong in this case (not saying they were right), scrape that, but a better design, at the cost of efficiency, would have been possible.

Answer (score 1):

You're not really asking a question anywhere, so let me comment a bit on when casting to something else than a `byte*` in cases as yours might be dangerous: if the returned pointer is cast to a pointer to a 2-byte type, 4-byte type, etc. and the value pointed at isn't correctly aligned for a type of that size, than a data misalignment error can occur, which on certain architectures will just flat out kill your process. For the `byte*` the cast is safe, since it points at the type of smallest alignment, *i.e.*, it's always aligned correctly.