# Verify base object is of a particular derived type

Tags: c++, rtti

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++03 project where I would like to verify if an object is of a certain type.

For example:

```
int main()
{
    struct A { virtual ~A() { }; };
    struct B : public A { };
    struct C : public A { };

    A* b = new B();
    A* c = new C();

    assert( typeof( b ) == typeof( B ) );
    assert( typeof( b ) != typeof( C ) );

    assert( typeof( c ) == typeof( C ) );
    assert( typeof( c ) != typeof( B ) );

    assert( typeof( b ) != typeof( c ) );
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to do this in C++03? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[typeinfo](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/type_info/)** for getting the type of an object.
Or you could use **[dynamic_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast)** to check if an pointer points to object of appropriate type.

Comment: `assert( typeid( *b ) == typeid( B ) )` appears to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dynamic_cast` to attempt to cast it to a base/derived type. If it does not return NULL then it is a base class or derived from that type (depending if you cast up the hierarchy or down)

Comment: assert( NULL != dynamic_cast< B* >( b ) );` Yup. that works too. Thanks!