# C++ like vs C like casts?

Tags: c++, c, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular cast vs. static_cast vs. dynamic_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast)

i've been using C-like casts since i've been programming:

```
class* initializedClassInstance;
void* test = (void*) initializedClassInstance;
```

and i've been told somewhere that i should get used to C++ casts (static_cast, dynamic_cast...).

Is there a reason to prefer one over the other (C++ over C style)?
There is a difference between static cast and dynamic cast, right? But what is it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C-style casts are unsafe.

C++-style casts behave in another way. `static_cast` will give you a compilation error if it can't make the cast.
`dynamic_cast` on fail will cast to NULL if you are casting pointers, and throw an exception otherwise.

So this allows you to write a safer code.

Comment: dynamic_cast will return NULL only for pointers. For references an exception will be thrown

Comment: @Andrew, yes, that's a good point, thanks.

Comment: @KillianDS, that's what I meant. A good example for it is pointer casting, which allows you to cast almost anything.

Comment: Great, thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: my comment was more about the lack of explanation as to why C-style casts are unsafe. Without proper explanation this is (imo) a terrible answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. It give you checks. `static_cast` gives you compile time checks and `dynamic_cast` gives you runtime checks for example.

You can read more about `casts` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f6c9f8h%28v=vs.80%29)