# Polymorphism: Runtime-Casting Pointers

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers, casting, void-pointers

I am curious as to how casting pointers to derived and base-classes actually works.
Here is an example:

```
struct A {};
struct B : A {};

// Boxing a pointer to an instance of B
void* p = new B();
```

Now, let´s say I want to access possible members or methods of A through the pointer p.

```
A* a1 = (A*)p;
A* a2 = (A*)((B*)p);
```

Which one is correct? Is there a difference at all?
Could you tell me where I can get further information on this subject?

Comment: If you are using C++, then should prefer C++ style casts.

Comment: The only subtle diff I see is that in the second cast there is creation of two temp pointer objects whereas in first it's only one pointer object :P

Comment: @Mr.Anubis The difference is that the one with "two temp pointer objects" is the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, no difference in practice.

But there could be difference [if there is multiple inheritance](http://ideone.com/sqyBm):

```
#include <cstdio>

struct A { int x; };
struct B { int y; };

struct C : B, A {};

int main() {
    void* c = new C();
    printf("%p\n", c);             // 0x1000
    printf("%p\n", (A*) c);        // 0x1000
    printf("%p\n", (A*) ((C*) c)); // 0x1004
    return 0;
}
```

or the subclass has a virtual method but the parent does not<sup>[1]</sup>, including using virtual inheritance<sup>[2]</sup>.

In terms of the standard, as OP uses C-style cast, [which in this case is equivalent to `static_cast`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast).

The cast sequence `B*` → `void*` → `B*` → `A*` is valid, where the first two cast will return back the same pointer as required by §5.2.9[expr.static.cast]/13, and the last cast works as a pointer conversion §4.10[conv.ptr]/3.

However, the cast sequence `B*` → `void*` → `A*` will actually give *undefined* result, because, well, the result is not defined in §5.2.9/13 ☺.

---

[[1]](http://ideone.com/PizkU):

```
#include <cstdio>

struct A { int x; };
struct C : A { virtual void g() {} };

int main() {
    void* c = new C();
    printf("%p\n", c);              // 0x1000
    printf("%p\n", (A*) c);         // 0x1000
    printf("%p\n", (A*) ((C*) c));  // 0x1008
    return 0;
}
```

[[2]](http://ideone.com/4oCXu):

```
#include <cstdio>

struct A { int x; };
struct C : virtual A {};

int main() {
    void* c = new C();
    printf("%p\n", c);              // 0x1000
    printf("%p\n", (A*) c);         // 0x1000
    printf("%p\n", (A*) ((C*) c));  // 0x1008
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  
I think I understand what you describe in your post.  
For my purposes, it will do.

Comment: @DeadMG: `<iostream>` sucks, that's all.