# Calling function from derived class through base class that is not overridden

Tags: c++, inheritance

in C++;

Is there a way of calling a function from a derived class through the base class
even when the function is not overridden? In other words, I'm using a base class in
order to have heterogeneous containers without boost; I want to call a member function
that is only specific to a derived class...

Example:
(I just made this code up so there's probably a syntax error but hopefully you get the gist)

```
class Vehicle
{
  public:
   virtual void do_vehicle_stuff();
   // virtual void do_car_specific_stuff(); makes no sense here
}

class Car : public Vehicle
{
  public:
   void do_vehicle_stuff();
   void do_car_specific_stuff();
}

Car a,b;

list<Vehicle> vehicle_list;
vehicle_list.push_back(a);
vehicle_list.push_back(b);

vehicle_list.front().do_car_specific_stuff();
```

error: 'Class Vehicle' has no member named 'do_car_specific_stuff()'

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast

Comment: Surely it would make no sense to ask for the abstract thing to know details about the concrete thing?

Comment: I know of slicing as pmr mentions below but couldn't find an adequate workaround..

Answer (score 1):

You are slicing your classes when you insert them into the list. In
C++ subtype polymorphism (the kind of polymorphism you are using) only
works through references or pointers but not values. When you insert
your `carS` into the `list` they are converted to `VehicleS`.

An example:

```
Car c;
std::vector<Vehicle> vs;
vs.push_back(c); // slicing happens
vs.front(); // not a car anymore, but just a vehicle,
            // the Car-ness is lost through the copy operation
```

How do to it:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Vehicle>> vs;
vs.push_back(new Car());
vs.front(); // actually a Car
```

After you have resolved that fundamental flaw of your code, this might
help you:

```
Vehicle* vehiclep = new Car();
if(auto carp = dynamic_cast<Car*>(vehiclep)) {
  carp->do_car_specific_stuff();
}
```

This is a rather costly operation and usually an indication of a
design smell, so you might want to rethink what you are doing.

Comment: Nice! Believe me, I am rethinking how this is being implemented :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more appropriate design:

```
struct Vehicle
{
    virtual ~Vehicle() { }

    void do_vehicle_stuff()
    {
        vehicle_impl();
    }

private:
    virtual void vehicle_impl() = 0;
};

struct Car : Vehicle
{
private:
    virtual void vehicle_impl()
    {
        my_vehicle_stuff();
        my_car_specific_stuff();
    }

    void my_vehicle_stuff()      { /* what you had originally */ }
    void my_car_specific_stuff() { /* car-only stuff */ }
};

std::list<std::unique_ptr<Vehicle>> vehicles;

vehicles.emplace_back(new Car);
vehicles.emplace_back(new Motorcycle);
vehicles.emplace_back(new Carriage);
```