# C++ dynamic cast

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular cast vs. static_cast vs. dynamic_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast)

is there any harm in using static_cast when I know the type for sure?
Any issue if it has virtual functions?

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void foo();
};

class Derived1 {
public:
    virtual void foo();
    void bar();
};


Base* b1 = new Derived1();
Derived1* d1 = static_cast<Derived1*>b1;
d1->bar();
```

Comment: `static_cast` would be fine in that particular case...

Comment: Where exactly are you wanting to put static_cast?

Comment: On "Derived1* d1 = b1;" or it is not legal.