# C++ conversion Base* to Derived* and constness

Tags: c++, casting, compiler-errors, constants

Is conversion from `Base*` to `Derived*` always allowed ? Is conversion from `const Base*` to `const Derived*` always allowed ?

I am using Qt QSharedPointers. I have a QSharedPointer to `Base` object, that I want to convert to a QSharedPointer to a `Derived` object. I check beforehand that pointee is of type `Derived`.

Is it possible with 100% chance of success with

- `static_cast<QSP<Derived>>`
- `dynamic_cast<QSP<Derived>>`
- a direct cast `QSP<Derived>(my_base_pointer)`

?

For example, for direct conversion:

```
QSP<Derived> inpf = QSP<Derived>(my_base_pointer) ;
```

i have error

```
Error 1 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'Base *' to 'Derived *'
```

with `my_base_pointer` of type `const QSP<Base>`.

Is it because of constness ? Should I const_cast on top of that ? I guess constness is not root cause, since if i

```
const QSP<Derived> inpf = static_cast<const QSP<Derived>>(my_base_pointer);
```

same error occurs.

Comment: The error message should tell you if constness is a problem, and it doesn't look like it in this case.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks, i checked with another static_cast to const, and updated my post, see above

Comment: How `QSP<T>` works with base/derived types has little to do with how pointers work with base/derived types, other than `QSP<T>` trying to duplicate pointer semantics or maybe using it under the hood.

Comment: @Yakk youre right. do you know how to deal with conversion and QSP ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're feeding the `QSP<Derived>` constructor a `Base*` pointer, which won't work. As long as you're *sure* the pointer really is a `Derived*` you should be able to static_cast it:

```
QSP<Derived> inpf = QSP<Derived>(static_cast<Derived*>(my_base_pointer)) ;
```

If the base class has at least one virtual function, it's safer to use `dynamic_cast` in this situation since that's what it was created for. If the pointer isn't actually a pointer to the derived class you'll get a NULL pointer.

Comment: Mark, kick me in the head and remind me whether it is possible to use `dynamic_cast<>` to throw an exception if it fails, or whether you have to code that logic yourself. I honestly don't remember. Just curious.(and +1)

Comment: @MarkRansom what about `QSP<Derived> inpf = static_cast<QSP<Derived>(my_base_pointer) ;` with `my_base_pointer` of type `QSP<Base>`

Comment: @WhozCraig, I think I have it wrong - `dynamic_cast` appears to throw always according to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast). I don't know how I got the impression it would return a NULL. I'll have to change my answer.

Comment: @antitrust I don't know the details of Qt shared pointers so I don't know if it would handle that, it's completely up to the Qt implementation.

Comment: @MarkRansom `std::bad_cast` will happen with references, not pointers. "Otherwise, the runtime check fails. *If the dynamic_cast is used on pointers, the null pointer value of type new_type is returned.* If it was used on references, the exception std::bad_cast is thrown."

Comment: @Yakk, now I'm doubly an idiot. Thanks. I've edited the answer back to my original and I'm going to need to check my reading comprehension in the future.

Comment: @WhozCraig, you get a NULL pointer if you're casting a pointer and a `std::bad_cast` exception if you're casting a reference. You don't have any control over it.

Comment: @MarkRansom Totally makes sense when you think about it. Can init a pointer to NULL, no such valid beast on a ref-initializer. Sorry for the temporary insanity. Good answer(s).

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called a **downcast**. For details, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast/1255015#1255015).

Comment: then just consider my question to be how to downcast a QSharedPointer under normal pressure and temperature conditions. `QSP<Derived> inpf_filter = static_cast<QSP<Derived>>(my_base_QSP) ;` is not working and i am sad.

Answer (score 0):

There is no implicit conversion from `Base*` to `Derived*`. That's because a pointer to `Base` does not have to point to a `Derived` object. If you're sure that it does, use a `static_cast`: `static_cast<Derived*>(base_pointer)`. If you're not sure, and `Base` has at least one virtual function, use a `dynamic_cast`: `dynamic_cast<Derived*>(base_pointer)`; this will do the conversion if the pointer points to an object of type `Derived`, and it will return a null pointer if it does not.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, question is about `QSharedPointer`, and generic answer for conversion `Base*` to `Derived*` does not fit this special case.

Diving in Qt docs, we find interesting member method for `QSharedPointer`, `staticCast`.

First, i came up with this code:

```
QSP<Derived> inpf_filter = my_base_QSP->staticCast<Derived>() ;
```

Since my `QSP` is a pointer type, I am `->` above calls `staticCast()` not on the `QSP` but on the pointee. So, I had an error again: `staticCast()` is not a member of `Base` class. I corrected into

```
QSP<Derived> inpf_filter = my_base_QSP.staticCast<Derived>() ;
```

and this compiles. `QSharedPointer` also supports `dynamicCast()`. In this, if cast cannot be performed, null pointer is returned.

Answer (score 0):

`QSharedPointer`s have an entire set of casting mechanisms:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsharedpointer.html#qSharedPointerCast

For a `QSharedPointer<U>`:

```
QSharedPointer ( const QSharedPointer<T> & other )
QSharedPointer<X>   constCast () const
QSharedPointer<X>   dynamicCast () const
QSharedPointer<X>   objectCast () const
QSharedPointer<X>   staticCast () const
```

The constructor works if `T` is a subtype of `U`.

`const`, `dynamic` and `static` cast work like the `_cast` operators of C++.

`object` does a `qobject_cast`.

Performing `_cast` operators on shared pointer types is generally a bad idea if you store the result in another shared pointer -- in order to safely cast a shared pointer that is non-intrusive, you need to do shared-pointer aware casting.