# How to convert a float to an int in modern C++

Tags: c++, casting, floating-point

As strange as it may seems, I can't find how to cleanly convert a `float` to an `int`.

This technique

```
int int_value = (int)(float_value + 0.5);
```

triggers a

```
warning: use of old-style cast
```

in gcc.

So, what is the modern-style, simple way to convert a `float` to an `int` ? (I accept the loss of precision of course)

Comment: The most modern way is `std::round`.

Comment: what does `int int_value = float_value + .5f;` do? Hint: 0.5 is a double.

Comment: @chris `round` will return a float. You could call `lround` but that returns a long, not an int. Oh, now I see that you're only talking about the rounding part, not the casting to int part. That'll teach me to read the entire question before commenting :-)

Comment: @Praetorian, Though I believe it is guaranteed to return something that you can truncate to the right number. I honestly forgot `lround` existed. There's a decent chance `long` will be the same size as `int`, too.

Comment: as a side note many(expert term :))  floats cant be casted to int because they are out of int range

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Josh pointed out in the comments, `+ 0.5` is not very reliable. For extra security you could combine a `static_cast` with `std::round` like so:

```
int int_value = static_cast<int>(std::round(float_value));
```

For the casting part, see [this excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast) for an explanation.

Comment: `+ 0.5` is a surprisingly unreliable way to round, due to floating point math issues.  See http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/02/nearbyintf1.

Comment: The `static_cast` does absolutely nothing here; once you've done `std::round`, you can just forget it (and get undefined behavior if the flow doesn't fit), or you can assign the results to a `float`, and check against `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` and `std::numeric_limits<int>::min` before doing the assignment.  (The `lexical_cast` is a very bad idea, since it doesn't work.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Couldn't omitting the cast generate warnings about precision loss?

Comment: @VictorSand A compiler can warn about anything it feels like, including in the presence of a cast.  In practice, though... an explicit cast is the traditional way of telling the compiler you know what you're doing, and that this isn't an oversight, so yes, I would expect the cast to have an impact on warnings.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
int int_value = static_cast<int>(float_value + 0.5);
```

FYI: [different casts in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast) gave a very good explanation about those 4 casts introduced in C++.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider

```
int int_value = boost::lexical_cast<int>(float_value);
```

lexical_cast has the benefit of working for all primitive types, and stl strings etc. It also means you don't have to do the (float_value + 0.5) stuff.

Comment: This won't work if the intermediate string contains a decimal point though, and that's likely for a float. Or, if the float is huge. Further, for rounding of negative values, you want to subtract 0.5, so rounding isn't that easy anyway.