# How can i get extract integer number from float number modulus?

Tags: c++

```html
const int npart = 500;
double  x[npart], y[npart], z[npart];
bedheight of yaxis, ly=20, x_axis lx=20 and z_axis lz=20
int cell_height=4;
 
const int number_cell = 5;// (ly/cell_height);
int counter2[number_cell];
int cell_particle;

for (h=0;h<number_cell;h++)
      {
    counter2[h]=0;
      }
          for (i = 0; i < npart; i++)
          {
                 //cell_particle=int(y[i]) % cell_height;
                 cell_particle= int(fmod (y[i],cell_height));
              counter2[cell_particle]=counter2[cell_particle]+1;
           }
cout<<"particle counter="<<counter2[j]<<"      cell number="<<cell_particle<<"     position="<<(y[j])<<endl;
 sol_fract=counter2[i]*(Volume of particle/(lx*lz*cell_height));

Could you please tell why the counter2[cell_particle] and sol_fract is contain wrong value? I am waiting for your suggestion.
```

```
int number_cell=20;
int  counter2[20];
double y[500];
int cell_height=4;

for (h=0;h<number_cell;h++)

      {
        counter2[h]=0;
      }
        for (i = 0; i < npart; i++)

        {
         cell_particle=int((y[i]) % cell_height);
         counter2[cell_particle]=counter2[cell_particle]+1;
            }
cout<<"particle counter="<<counter2[j]<<"      cell number="<<cell_particle<<endl;

output: error: invalid operands of types ‘double’ and ‘double’ to binary ‘operator%
```

How can i get interger number from double values of modulus? It is noted that the value of y[i]=4.5, 8.9, 6 etc. I need integer value to put on counter2 array, but the problem is that conversion (error message is error: invalid operands of types ‘double’ and ‘double’ to binary ‘operator% ). Could you please tell me how can i solve the problem?

Comment: int int_value = static_cast<int>(std::round(float_value)); [Already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16570752/4953089)

Answer (score 1):

With `int((y[i]) % cell_height)` you attempt to convert the *whole* expression `(y[i]) % cell_height` into an `int`.

You probably want something like `int(y[i]) % cell_height`, which converts `y[i]` to an `int` *before* the modulo. Or what I prefer `static_cast<int>(y[i]) % cell_height`.

Or if you want to use floating-point modulo use [`std::fmod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I am used format according to your comments , but still now the programming out put shows error and output shows //invalid operands of types ‘int’ and ‘double’ to binary ‘operator%’. . could you please give me another idea?

Comment: Hi the programming is running but the out put is found wrong. I found the output hold counter2[cell_particle] is wrong value, but i dont understand why?

Answer (score 0):

To get 5 out of 5.4 **or** 6 out of 5.6 , you can easily round the number `ceil(5.4)` if you want to get the higher proportions or `floor(5.6)` if to Lowers ones

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I am used format according to your comments , but still now the programming out put shows error and output shows //invalid operands of types ‘int’ and ‘double’ to binary ‘operator%’. . could you please give me another idea?