# Java's casting and C++'s casting

Tags: java, c++, casting

I come from C++ and just know some Java, but there is one thing that I don't fully understand about java is the casting.  In c++, we have [Regular cast vs. static_cast vs. dynamic_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast).  In java, we have casting between primitive types and object types (known as boxing and unboxing), casting between primitive types, casting using `Class` function, and sometimes we perform unchecked casting.  Is there a direct mapping from Java's casting system to C++'s casting system? are they equivalent? or is there something that is unique in one side?

Comment: What's a "regular cast"?!

Comment: @KerrekSB: The link I provided explains it.

Comment: I would not consider boxing as casting, as it creates new instances. It is just a compiler convenience for doing `new Integer(myInt)` and all that.

Comment: No.  In Java you have primitive casts, boxing/unboxing, and reference type coercion.  The first two actually alter the data value.  The third type of cast simply asserts to the compiler and JVM what the object type is -- there is no change to the data value.  This third type is ALWAYS checked.  These three concepts are quite distinct and different from each other and have (rather unfortunately) "overloaded" the term/notation of "cast", leading to considerable confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know C++, the Java object model can be explained fairly easily. Java variables of class type are *references* to dynamically created objects of the corresponding type. An initialized Java variable `T x = new T();` corresponds closely to a C++ pointer: `T * px = new T;`

In Java, all class types inherit from the polymorphic type `Object`, and thus all pointers can be used for RTTI: All casts of Java class-type variables are what `dynamic_cast` is in C++. So Java's `(S) x` corresponds to `dynamic_cast<S *>(px)` in C++, with the same failure mode that a null result indicates that the dynamic types aren't related.

All the other C++ pointer casts are unsafe and have no equivalent in Java. I don't know if Java has scalar conversions like integer-to-floating point; if so, then those would correspond closely to the C++ conversions.

Boxing and primitive types are a rather separate and unrelated issue. If you wanted something like that in C++ you'd have some kind of `template <typename T> struct Box` with a conversion-to-`T` opera­tor.

Answer (score 1):

In short:

Think about casts from built-in types as static_cast's and

think about casts between objects as dynamic_cast's in C++.