# Forced necessity of dynamic_cast operator in C++

Tags: c++, casting, dynamic-cast

`dynamic_cast` is generally used when we have a base class pointer and want to downcast it to a derived class. For instance,

```
class A
{
      public:
      virtual void foo();
};

class B : public A 
{
      public:
      void foo();
};

main()
{
    A* a = new B();
    B* b = dynamic_cast<B*> (a);
}
```

But, the same can also be accomplised by using `C-style` cast:

```
B* b = (B*)a;
```

So, my question is what are the circumstances/cases where it becomes completely necessary to use this operator i.e. there is no other choice?

Comment: This was said many times before: use `static_cast` if you are sure that object pointed by `a` is actually `B` and `dynamic_cast` if you aren't sure (it will return NULL for pointers or throw `std::bad_cast` for references if it isn't). Avoid C-style cast in C++ code as they're hard to find and don't stand out.

Comment: Imagnie what happens when a actually points to an A ...

Comment: The related posts, specifically [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast?rq=1), might give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't actually know that `a` points to object of type `B` `dynamic_cast` will return a null pointer, which you can check and handle the situation accordingly. With C-style cast you get a pointer, but when you try to use it undefined behavior happens.

Comment: Thanks. I never knew `dynamic_cast` has the capability of returning NULL!

Comment: Technically speaking, the cast itself (without subsequently using the bad pointer) is already UB.

Answer (score 4):

> But, the same can also be accomplised by using C-style cast:

No, it cannot :)

By definition, The C-Style cast will try to perform a series of `const_cast`, `static_cast`, and `reinterpret_cast`<sup>1</sup> to achieve your desired cast but **not** `dynamic_cast`. So, essentially, here C-style cast is equivalent to a `static_cast` which will have undefined behavior if the actual dynamic types won't match (conversely, in this situation the dynamic cast will return `nullptr` in case of pointers and throw `std::bad_cast` in case of references).

That is to say, if you're **certain** that you're casting to the right type, then use `static_cast` (or C-style cast, but I personaly don't like it). But if you are not certain, then use `dynamic_cast`

<sub>1 C-Style cast can be used to also cast to a private base, which can't be done with the aforementioned series of C++-Style casts</sub>

Answer (score 2):

If your question is when you should use **dynamic_cast over C-style cast**, the answer is always (that is, if you have to choose between C-style cast and dynamic_cast, always prefer dynamic_cast).

In general though, strive to never use C-style casts in C++. They are difficult to locate by a tool (unless that tool is a compiler) and they lead to code that has to be read explicitly looking for casts whenever you refactor (sources of bugs).

If your question is when you should use **dynamic_cast over designs that do not require it**, the answer is almost never. Generally, you should avoid designs that require your implementation to downcast pointers or references. When your implementation forces you to down-cast, it is most often a sign of poor design (i.e. the correct solution is probably refactoring, not down-casting).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to some of the answers above, even if you ignore the fact `dynamic_cast` is clever, using c style casts in c++ code as a replacement for `static`/`const`/`reinterpret` cast is *really dangerous*.

Depending on what is visible at the time of the cast [which can change if header files get removed for example], a c-style cast may not do pointer arithmetic correctly and leave you ending up with a garbage pointer.

You never want adding or removing header files to change the meaning of your code. C++ casts do not have this problem, if the compiler cannot work out what it should do you'll get a compilation failure, and not the random runtime crashes you may get with c style casts.

Answer (score 0):

One situation in which a dynamic_cast returns a different (and correct) result is when you’re casting from a non-leftmost base class:

```
class A { 
public:
   int x; 
}

class B {
public:
   virtual void foo();
};

class C : public A, public B
{
     public:
     void foo();
};

main()
{
   B* b = new C();
   C* c = dynamic_cast<C*>(b);
}
```

A C-style cast would return an incorrect pointer here.