# typecasting objects in C++ (please explain the output)

Tags: c++, type-conversion

how does this line work assuming `b` is the base class from which `D1` is derived and `Tell` is a virtual function which is defined in `d1` and as well as `b`

```
D1 d1;
((D1)((B)d1)).Tell();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem right, as C-Style casts tries different C++ casts in an order but [`dynamic_cast` isn't one of those](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17598055/183120).

Comment: I se no `b` in your code. Did you mean `B`?

Answer (score 2):

It probably doesn't work, unless `D1` has a constructor to convert from `B`. If that's the case, it "works" by creating a temporary object and calling the function on that (after creating yet another temporary of type `B`); which is almost certainly not what you want to do.

If you're actually casting to pointer or reference types, then it "works" if `d1` has type `D1` since the conversions cancel each other out; but if it's another type, you're casting to the wrong type and invoking undefined behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

You mentioned d1 is derived from b but have't mentioned about D1.
Assuming b is the base class & d1, D1 both derived from b & Tell is virtual, so it will call the body of Tell from D1