# c++ polymorphism : return type of a virtual method

Tags: c++, polymorphism, return-type

My main class is :

```
class Data{
public:
    Data(std::string name):name_(name){};
    virtual ~Data(){};

protected:
    std::string name_;
};
```

Since I'd like to allow any kind of data, I use a template to create my inherited class :

```
template<typename Type>
class GenericData : public Data{
 public:
    GenericData(std::string name, Type t);

private:
    Type t_;
};

template<typename Type>
GenericData<Type>::GenericData(std::string name, Type t):
    Data(name),
    t_(t)
{}
```

The third class is a collection of (Generic)Data :

```
class Input{
public:
    Input();
    ~Input();

private:
    std::vector<Data*> d_;
};

Input::Input(){
    d_.push_back(new GenericData("double",3.2);
    d_.push_back(new GenericData("int",2);
}

Input::~Input(){
    for(unsigned int i(0);i<d_.size();i++){
    delete d_[i];
    d_[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

The thing that I don't know how to do is to get the `t_` value from from the `Input` class. I'd like to have a `templata<typename Type> Type Input::get(unsigned int i)` method that returns `t_`. I guess that I should create a virtual method in `Data` and another method in `GenericData` but I can't make it work.

Comment: `t_` belongs to `GenericData`, you can't get it through base poitner

Comment: is there a way to get it from Input?

Comment: @billz he is trying to use polymorphism, i.e virtual getter.. but not sure it will work..

Comment: " I'd like to have a templata<typename Type> Type Input::get(unsigned int i)". What's wrong with that?

Comment: if you are willing to go old school, you could return a `void *` pointer

Comment: @KarthikT it won't coz virtual getter need return one type only. while GenericData may have any time. Or make `Data` template, then define `std::vector<Data<T> d_;`

Comment: How about `static_cast`? Like `static_cast<GenericData<int>*>(d_[1])->getT()`. Of course, will only know if you know the template type.

Comment: look into type erasure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Data{
public:
    Data(std::string name):name_(name){};
    virtual ~Data(){};

protected:
    std::string name_;
};

template<typename Type>
class GenericData : public Data{
 public:
    GenericData(std::string name, Type t);

    Type Get() { return t_; }
private:
    Type t_;
};

template<typename Type>
GenericData<Type>::GenericData(std::string name, Type t):
    Data(name),
    t_(t)
{}

class Input{
public:
    Input() {}
    ~Input();

    void Add(Data*v) {d_.push_back(v);}
    template<typename T>
    T Get(int i) {
        return dynamic_cast< GenericData<T> *>(d_[i])->Get();
    }
private:
    std::vector<Data*> d_;
};

Input::~Input(){
    for(unsigned int i(0);i<d_.size();i++){
    delete d_[i];
    d_[i] = NULL;
    }
}

int main() {
        Input inp;
        inp.Add(new GenericData<int>("1", 1));
        inp.Add(new GenericData<double>("2", 2.0));
        std::cout << "1: " << inp.Get<int>(0) << "; 2: " << inp.Get<double>(1) << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: great, thanks ! but what does `dynamic_cast< GenericData<T> *>(d_[i])` make ?

Answer (score 1):

That's quite problematic. First of all, you have to provide some way to get it from Data, for example:

```
(inside GenericData)

public:
    T GetValue()
    {
        // Consider naming t_ more informative
        return t_;
    }
```

Secondly, you can create a generic method for getting data in Input:

```
(inside Input)

public:
    template <typename T>
    GenericData<T> * GetData(int index)
    {
        return dynamic_cast<GenericData<T> *>(_d[index]);
    }
```

or, simpler:

```
(inside Input)

public:
    template <typename T>
    T GetValue(int index)
    {
        return (dynamic_cast<GenericData<T> *>(_d[index]))->GetValue();
    }
```

Comment: This: `(GenericData<T> *)` is inappropriate cast in that case. And also question was how to get a value of type T.

Comment: And why is it inappropriate? Asker did not say, that he uses C++11.

Comment: @Spook: since when is dynamic_cast only C++11+ ?

Comment: Aside the fact that c-cast is inappropriate in c++ in general, in this case it would be wrong, because c-cast is implemented via reinterpret and static cast, and dynamic_cast it needed here. There is good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast
Also, dynamic_cast is not a c++11 feature, it's been in c++ since the beginning.

Comment: Ok, you're right on this one. I modified the code. Though the C-style cast would have worked too.