# What does this pointer between parentheses mean?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm having a problem to understand this line of code:

```
MyTable *t = (MyTable*)table;
```

Can someone explain what's happening on the right side of the equal sign?

Answer (score 2):

The pointer (or whatever it is) `table` is casted to the type "pointer to `MyTable`".

Answer (score 1):

`(MyTable*)` is not a pointer. It's a c-style cast to the type " pointer to `MyTable`" .

`table` is presumably a pointer which is being converted by the cast.

Please not that c-style casts are not always your best option in c++ when dealing with OO design.

See : [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast) for details.

**Edit:**

The language tag on this question was c++ at first.

Answer (score 1):

The text in parentheses is not a pointer, it is a type name. `MyTable *` is a pointer to `MyTable`.

A type name in parentheses is a cast.

A cast performs a conversion.

The cast `(MyTable *)` converts a value to a pointer to `MyTable`.

There are rules for converting pointers that can be somewhat tricky, so conversions like this might or might not result in valid code. The code `MyTable *t = (MyTable *) table;` is probably valid code if one of the following is true:

- `table` is already a pointer to a `MyTable`, either directly or by having been properly converted in various ways.
- `table` points to (enough) space allocated with `malloc` or another memory-management routine.
- `table` is equal to NULL.

The code is probably not valid if:

- `table` points to some kind of object other than a `MyTable`.
- `table` is not a pointer.

There are some other specialized situations that are valid, but I am omitting the details since they are specialized. (These include integers that have been converted from pointers and conversions between pointers to aggregates and pointers to their first elements.)

Answer (score 0):

It is casting `table` to a type of "pointer to MyTable".

MyTable is a class or struct, probably. A pointer *to* MyTable is a type of it's own (`MyTable*`).

Answer (score 0):

What is confusing you? Whatever `table` is, it is casted into a pointer to `MyTable`. This way, if the cast is possible, the assignment will be valid.

Answer (score 0):

MyTable *t = (MyTable*)table;
Whenever this situation occurs think like this
   firstly on right:
()are evaluated first means 
 table is converted to a pointer of type MyTable.look at following example

```
    when you say 
     float x;
     int y;
     x=y;//read below
```

when tou do x=y as type of y is int and you are assigning it to a float
Here implici conversion is carried out which is

```
 x=(float)y;
```

Which is the way you are doing
 firstly table is converted to type  MyTable* and then is assigned