# c++ additional features in subclass not in superclass

Tags: c++, inheritance, subclass

Suppose I have the following code:

```
class A 
{
     public:
         void Funct1();
};

class B : public A
{
      public:
          void Func1();
          void Func2();
}
```

In main()

Declaring Object of type A

```
  A b = new B;
  b.Func1() // can access it;
  b.Func2() // cannot access
```

How can I make or access Func2 using object b especially in main

Comment: Start with code that compiles. `b` is of type `A`; not `A*` or `B*`. `Public` isn't valid either, and after you sort all of that out, read about `dynamic_cast<>` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used).

Comment: you cannot assign a pointer (`new B`) to a non-pointer variable (`A`).

Comment: Is it on purpose that you have `A::Funct1()`, instead of `A::Func1()`.

Comment: Don't forget to declare `A::Func1()` as `virtual` or overriding it won't work properly. Specifically, if you correct the declaration of `b` to `A *b = new B();`, then `b->Func1()` will actually call `A::Func1()`, not `B::Func1()`.

Comment: Thanks i was suppose to declare as pointers i just forgot to type that in as making it A* b = new B. Suppose i did not want to put a virtual function func2 in A. I can easily solve the issue with that method. I meant for a case maybe you have 10 subclasses, are you going to virtualize every member functions even if some dont apply to other derived classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use static_cast

```
A *b = new B;
B *bb = static_cast<B*> (b);
```

through bb you can access `Func2()`.

Comment: This is usually a sign of design issues in the inheritance hierarchy. It would be better to use dynamic_cast because b can hold any objects which inherit from A, not only B objects. dynamic_cast can check if this conversion works.

Comment: Thanks that works. After lot googling i came across this B*  bb = (B*) A;

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems in your code.

1. You are using `Void` instead of `void`. Notice the uppercase vs lowercase difference.
2. You are using `Funct1` in `A` but `Func1` in `B`. You can change `Funct1` to `Func1`
3. There is a missing `;` at the end of `B`.
4. Using `B` instead of `new B`. You have:

   ```
   A b = new B;
   ```

   That is a syntactically incorrect line. You can make it either

   ```
   A b = B();
   ```

   or

   ```
   A* b = new B();
   ```

Even after that change, you still have the problems you described.

There are two ways you can solve this:

1. Use `B b` instead `A b`.

   ```
   B b;
   b.Func1();
   b.Func2();
   ```
2. Use a `virtual` member function.

   ```
    class A 
    {
         Public:
             void Func1();
             virtual void Func2();
    };

    class B : public A
    {
          Public:
              void Func1();
              virtual void Func2();
    };
   ```

   Then, you can use:

   ```
   B b;
   A* aPtr = &b;
   aPtr->Func1();
   aPtr->Func2();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function which gets argument of Type A. Then you can send an argument of type A or B to this function,polymorphism works and the function inside class A or B works wrt what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In a statically typed language like C++, you can only call methods corresponding to the **static** type of an object in the current scope. In main, you declared b with static type A, restricting it to the interface defined in class A. If you want polymorphism, you need to declare the polymorphic functions in A and also add the virtual keyword.

Answer (score 0):

If object-oriented programming doesn't make sense for the problem you are trying to solve, don't use it. In C++, you don't need to put everything in classes, let alone in class hierarchies. Start with simple free-standing functions and use classes if you need them.

That being said, if you really insist, use [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast). In some situations, this may even be a legitimate choice. But if you feel that you need it all the time, then you must review your understanding of object-oriented programming.