# at runtime how to determine actual type of non-polymorphic type

Tags: c++

I have such declarations:

```
struct InstrumentInfo
{
    std::string Name;
    TradingStatus Status;
    myDecimal MinStep;
    std::string ISIN;
    myDecimal limit_down;
    myDecimal limit_up;
};

struct FortsDerivativeInfo : InstrumentInfo
{
    std::string ShortIsin;
    int IsinId;
    std::string CodeVcb;
    myDecimal StepPrice;
    int LotVolume;
    myDecimal exch_pay;
};

struct StockInfo : InstrumentInfo
{
    int LotSize;
};
```

I've trited to write such code:

```
if (auto si = dynamic_cast<StockInfo*>(ii))
{
    LOT_SIZE = si->LotSize;
}
else
{
    LOT_SIZE = 1;
}
```

This doesn't compile, I receive "error C2683: 'dynamic_cast' : 'InstrumentInfo' is not a polymorphic type". How can I fix this error?

If I replace `dynamic_cast` to `static_cast` code compiles, but as `static_cast` doesn't perform any runtime checks I'm afraid this will not work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular cast vs. static\_cast vs. dynamic\_cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast)

Comment: @gha.st: I would not say so. The issue is less about choosing the appropriate cast and more about making `dynamic_cast` work or coding an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run-time type information is available only for types that have at least one virtual function (i.e. "polymorphic types"). The only way to make `dynamic_cast` work is to make the base type polymorphic - for example, by declaring its destructor `virtual`.

A better approach would be removing the need for the cast altogether - for example, by making a virtual `lotSize` function:

```
struct InstrumentInfo
{
    std::string Name;
    TradingStatus Status;
    myDecimal MinStep;
    std::string ISIN;
    myDecimal limit_down;
    myDecimal limit_up;
    virtual int lotSize() const { return 1; }
};

struct StockInfo : InstrumentInfo
{
    int LotSize;
    virtual int lotSize() const { return LotSize; }
};

InstrumentInfo ii;
LOT_SIZE = ii.lotSize();
```

Answer (score 0):

No run-time type information is available for non-polymorphic types (types without virtual functions).

Adding a virtual destructor in `InstrumentInfo` will give you RTTI and make `dynamic_cast` work, though the better way to solve your problem is, as pointed out in the other answer, to use a virtual member function that returns lot size. It's a good idea to use a virtual destructor regardless of RTTI anyway, because otherwise you have some serious problems if you do this:

```
InstrumentInfo * info = new FortsDerivativeInfo;
delete info;
```

This results in undefined behavior (deleting a derived object through a base class pointer without a virtual destructor).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: `dynamic_cast` only works on polymorphic types, so you have to look for alternatives.

---

The longer answer is that you have alternatives:

- the simplest is to add a `virtual` method (the destructor of the base class), and your code will compile as is
- but in general, if you can use `virtual` method, create one that will avoid this ugly cast
- other alternatives exist, such as having an `enum` in the base class that indicate which child is currently instantiated; they are not as automated so are of last recourse