# typecasting a pointer with static_cast<>

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

Excuse me if this is a stupid question, but I can't get my head around the following piece of code:

```
struct myStruct
  {
    static void func1(const event, void* pthis)
    {
       myStruct& foo = *static_cast<myStruct*>(pthis);

       if(event.action != ...).... return;
       if(event.action == ...) foo.func2(); 
    }

    void func2()
    {}
  }
```

So... pthis is casted to a static pointer of type myStruct? Does this mean foo is of type 'reference to myStruct', and is equal to the value pointed to by pthis.

Essentially foo is pointing to myStruct, without access to instances of myStruct?

I really don't get it...

Comment: `*static_cast` it does dereference after cast

Comment: [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in?rq=1)

Comment: Why not `func1()` just accepts a reference of `myStruct`? what's the purpose of this design...my head really can't get around that :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So... pthis is casted to a static pointer of type myStruct?

A [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) has nothing to do with [`static`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) variables. It's explained in [Regular cast vs. static_cast vs. dynamic_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1255015/3920237) that `static_cast` can be used to reverse implicit conversions to void pointer.

> Essentially foo is pointing to myStruct, without access to instances of myStruct?

No, `foo` is not "pointing" to anything. `foo` is a reference being bound to the object dereferenced by `pThis`. `foo` can call member methods just like `(*pThis)` can.

Comment: So foo is a reference, used to call member functions of myStruct. And thanks to static_cast the void pointer pthis can be used as any type of pointer?