# Is this a valid downcasting

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a cpp code where in class c is derived from class b and class b is derived from class a.

Now class b has some public data member. So I am creating a instance of class c on heap passing its pointer to another class as pointer to a and there it is downcasting that pointer to pointer of class b and then printing public variables of class b.

Is this a valid downcasting. I am asking because just change of compiler has broken this working code.

I am including below code snippet which captures problem I am having.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class grand
{
};
class parent : public grand
{
    public : parent(){i=0;}
    int i;
    parent(int j){ i = j;}
    void set(int j){i = j;}
};

class child : public parent{


public: child(){};
};

void print ( grand* ptr)
{
    parent *p = (parent*) ptr;
    std::cout << std::endl << p->i << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    child c;
    c.set(9);
    print(&c);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: C-style casting should be avoided here. You should probably read up on [various casting techniques](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast) and their applications. In this case you should change the definition of `print` to accept only `parent*` and let the compiler cast for you because you can't be guaranteed that your cast is valid otherwise.

Comment: Does your actual code use multiple inheritance by any chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a valid downcasting.

Yes. Your cast internally applies `static_cast`, which, according to §5.2.9/11, will give you the right result. If the argument for `ptr` doesn't point to a `parent`, the result of the cast is undefined - and so would the execution of the following code be.

Downcasting of polymorphic types in C++ works via `dynamic_cast`. Your `grand` class above isn't polymorphic - you have to add at least a virtual destructor to `grand` to make it polymorphic. Otherwise you'll get a compiler error with the following code.

```
parent *p = dynamic_cast<parent*>(ptr); // Once grand is polymorphic...
```

And check whether the result, `p`, is non-zero. Only this method reveals (at runtime) whether the cast worked! All others either invoke undefined behavior or undefined, non-zero values.

Some notes:

- Downcasting is almost always a sign of bad design. Avoid it if possible, using - for example - virtual (print) functions.
- `print` should take a pointer to `const` since it doesn't modify any data members.

Answer (score 0):

Your code, as written, is in fact valid, but there are a bunch of observations I'd like to make. Note that it's valid only because the object you pass to `print` is a `parent` or further derived class.

Then note that since you have to cast it the `print` function it's much safer to just change the function signature to take a`parent` instead of a `grand` and then you don't have to worry about the casting.

Then note that a likely cause of your problem is that in the file that does the cast, the compiler *doesn't* see the relationship between `grand` and `parent` so your C-style cast falls back to `reinterpret_cast` which is *not* what you want. If you can't change the signature of `print` at least change the cast to `static_cast` (or possibly `dynamic_cast`, but you can't do that in your example because the classes aren't polymorphic) so that the compiler will fail to compile when it can't see the class relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a C-style cast you should apply a `dynamic_cast` or a at least a `static_cast` if you compile without RTTI (runtime type information) for some reason.

Your C-style cast is the same as a `reinterpret_cast`, which essentially interprets the memory pointed to *as if* an object of type `parent` would have been constructed there. *But*, every compiler may have a different memory layout of derived classes, thus that may work in some circumstances but there's no guarantee.

Comment: Actually a C-style cast attempts a bunch of casts and `reinterpret_cast` is only the last resort.

Comment: In this case, the C-style cast is equivalent to `static_cast`, since there is a valid downcast from `grand` to `parent`. But it should still be avoided; it would fall back to `reinterpret_cast`, giving bogus runtime results, where `static_cast` would give a useful compile-time error.