# Static_cast integer address to pointer

Tags: c++, casting

Why do you need a C-style cast for the following?

```
int* ptr = static_cast<int*>(0xff); // error: invalid static_cast from type 'int' 
                                    // to type 'int*'
int* ptr = (int*) 0xff; // ok.
```

Comment: You can also use `reinterpret_cast` which the C-style cast will eventually use anyway. Still not a good idea though.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`static_cast` can only cast between two **related** types.  An integer is not related to a pointer and vice versa, so you need to use `reinterpret_cast` instead, which tells the compiler to *reinterpret* the bits of the integer as if they were a pointer (and vice versa):

```
int* ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(0xff);
```

Read the following for more details:

[Type conversions](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/)

Answer (score 4):

You need a C-style cast or directly the `reinterpret_cast` it stands for when casting an integer to a pointer, because the standard says so for unrelated types.

The standard mandates those casts there, because

1. you are doing something dangerous there.
2. you are doing something very seldom useful.
3. you are doing something highly implementation-dependent.
4. most times, that is simply a programming-error.

[When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)
[Regular cast vs. static_cast vs. dynamic_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast)

Answer (score 4):

Being late to the party I found that the following works only using static casts:

```
int* ptr1 = static_cast<int*>(static_cast<void*>(static_cast<unsigned char*>(nullptr) + 0xff));
```

This way you don't translate the constant directly to a pointer, instead you add it as a bytewise offset to the nullptr.

Answer (score 1):

[CppCoreGuidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Pro-type-reinterpretcast) discourage the use of `reinterpret_cast` and the static analysis tool that we're using [enforces](https://rules.sonarsource.com/cpp/RSPEC-3630/) that.

Since we need to turn machine addresses into pointers, I tried [xmoex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73176571/297373)'s solution, but that leads to this warning: "arithmetic on a null pointer treated as a cast from integer to pointer is a GNU extension".

So I found out that to cheat the compiler, you just have to extract `static_cast<unsigned char*>(nullptr)` in a variable.

I came out with this small template function:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename P>
constexpr auto numberToPointer(T value) -> P*
{
    unsigned char* ucharnullptr = nullptr;
    return static_cast<P*>(ucharnullptr + value);
}
```

To be used like this:

```cpp
unsigned int u = 0x123;
void* ptr = numberToPointer<unsigned int, void>(u);
```