# Is there any advantage in using static_cast rather than C-style casting for non-pointer types?

Tags: c++, casting, compile-time

I am well aware of the advantage in using `static_cast` rather than C-style casting for pointer types.

If the pointer types are incompatible, then:

- `static_cast` will yield a compile-time error at a specific line within the source code
- C-style casting might lead to a runtime error at a "random" point in the execution of the program

But I am unable to find any similar example for non-pointer types.

In other words, both casting methods yield the same result for non-pointer types.

Is that correct, or have I missed anything?

If yes, is `static_cast` used for non-pointer types only in order to maintain coding consistency?

Comment: A C-style cast doesn't care whether input or output are a pointer. It will happily convert between pointers and non-pointers.

Comment: I found a nice explanation [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast).

Comment: @Dinal24: It doesn't refer to my specific question regarding the advantages of `static_cast` over regular cast in the case of **non-pointer types**.

Comment: Item 2 in Scott Meyers' most excellent `Effective C++` book has a dedicated section labelled "Prefer C++-style casts" about this exact topic.

Comment: @rubenvb: It doesn't refer to my specific question regarding the advantages of `static_cast` over regular cast in the case of **non-pointer types**.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of [this "canonical" question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast?lq=1). The answer to this question can be deduced from the one to the general one, but is not explicitly stated there.

Comment: @Angew: Thanks. Can you please reopen it?

Comment: @barakmanos Just did.

Comment: Well, the answers given here are *exactly* the same as for both other duplicates. Apart from an explicit "yes". Although [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/332086/256138) specifies exactly why you'd prefer C++ style casts for everything...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

One advantage which the other two answers didn't mention yet is that `static_cast` is much easier to spot. The meaning of parentheses is notoriously overloaded in C++ and it can be difficult to spot evil (or even incorrect) casts. When I see something ending in `_cast` though, it's like a mental speed bump: I slow down and carefully check why the type system is being subverted.

Comment: Readability... sometimes far more important than the technical reasons.

Comment: Readability and easy visual spotting are nice, but the real big advantage of static_cast over c style cast shows with CTRL+F.
Have you ever tried to find all existing c style casts in a major part of your codebase?

Comment: @Kaiserludi I suppose 'readability by tools' could also be considered 'readability'.

Comment: Er... This is not exactly as clear cut as it seems to be. The whole point of introducing C++-style casts is to distribute various responsibilities among different kinds casts instead of piling them all up onto C-style cast. However, even after that distribution, `static_cast` still appears to be doing too much. It covers two completely unrelated areas: non-trivial pointer casts (hierarchical upcasts and casts from `void *`) as well as arithmetic casts. Doing them all through `static_cast` actually makes them *harder* to spot.

Comment: I want a clear visual distinction between the former and the latter. I want `arithmetic_cast` as a separate kind of cast. But I want it to have a more compact name than a full blown `arithmetic_cast` (that would be unwieldy). This is where C-style cast fits in very nicely. C-style cast is for arithmetic casts, `static_cast` is for pointer casts. They are harder to spot, you say? I don't remember having any need to deliberately spot arithmetic casts. Pointer casts - yes, but not arithmetic casts. Arithmetic casts are natural. They are not supposed to be more "spottable" than, say, `+` operator.

Comment: matter of taste.. mental speed bumps can also just distract you from really relevant information

Answer (score 17):

I'm assuming that trivial uses of references to avoid pointers won't count.

In that case: a C-style cast can be:

- a `const_cast`
- a `static_cast`
- a `static_cast` followed by a `const_cast`,
- a `reinterpret_cast`
- a `reinterpret_cast` followed by a `const_cast`

with the exception that `static_cast`'s restrictions on inaccessible base classes are lifted.

`const_cast` only applies to pointers and references.

`reinterpret_cast` only applies to pointers and references. It does include pointer-to-integer conversions and vice versa, but that still involves a pointer type.

That special exception for `static_cast` only applies to pointers and references.

So yes, by excluding pointers and references, you've excluded everything that C-style casts support over a `static_cast`.

> If yes, is `static_cast` used for non-pointer types only in order to maintain coding consistency?

Let's go with an analogy: I wouldn't use a chainsaw to open a bag of chips. I could, but chainsaws are dangerous, so by using one, I'd introduce unnecessary risks. It's very easy to use a chainsaw wrong, and if I do use it wrong, there's no safety mechanism to prevent accidents.

Comment: A more vivid version of your analogy: you certainly can cut your toenails with a chainsaw, but you better know what you're doing.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe On the other hand, if you know what you're doing, you won't be cutting your toenails with a chainsaw. :)

Comment: The proper metaphor is that you should be damn sure it's a bag of chips which you open with your flame thrower instead of a knife, and not a bag of popcorn or dynamite which would blow up in your face, to varying degrees.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Heh, that sounds good. It works with chainsaws too: you'd better not use a chainsaw as an alternative to taking the lid off of a glass jar.

Answer (score 16):

> Is `static_cast` used for non-pointer types only in order to maintain coding consistency?

Not only that, but also to help maintain correctness and future compatibility.

It helps maintain correctness, since `static_cast` cannot do some casts which a C-style cast can. This helps if you make a mistake about some of the types involved, perhaps handling a pointer while being convinced it's an integer (and down several layers of templates and typedefs, that's not too difficult to imagine). So if you intend a `static_cast`, write one and get a compile-time error, you'll be told immediately that the types involved are not what you thought they were. With the C-style cast's "anything goes" attitude, you will not discover the mistake in time.

It also helps with future compatibility. If the types involved in the cast change later in the development, a `static_cast` will report an error where a C-style cast would just silently change its behaviour (to something most likely not intended).

Comment: "With the C-style cast I will not discover the mistake in time" - doesn't that hold only when casting between pointers? Can you give a non-pointer example of this claim?

Comment: @barakmanos I meant this paragraph as "you're 1000% convinced that you're casting integers, but one of them is really a pointer." Edited to clarify.

Comment: Or to put it another way, using `static_cast` helps you enforce this desirable constraint, that the source type is not a pointer. `int *ip = new int(); long j = static_cast<long>(*ip);` is a stupid example, but writing it like that catches the error of typoing `ip` for `*ip`, whereas `long(*ip)` doesn't catch it because `long(ip)` is a valid C-style cast.

Answer (score 6):

> is static_cast used for non-pointer types only in order to maintain coding consistency?

No (well - yes, but not only).

It is also easy to find/replace. This is important in case of refactorings, bug fixing, etc.

It is a constraint on the cast type allowed: Consider an example where you have a C-style cast (which works fine) on a variable, then you change the declaration of the casted variable, to something which renders the cast invalid (for example, you change `int x;` to `void * const x;`).

The C-style cast suddenly performs another function (i.e. `const_cast<...>(reinterpret_cast<...>(...)`) with the same code.

If you write the initial code with a static_cast instead of a C-style cast, the compiler will let you know that static_cast in there is not actually performing a static cast.

Comment: Yep, find/replace did occur to me a few hours after asking this question. Thanks.