# datatype pointers using *(datatype*)

Tags: c++

i started to learn a bit more about c++ and lately i see really often stuff like *(DWORD*)(x+y);

example:

```
    int number = 10;
int pointer;

pointer = *(int*)(number);

std::cout << "number: " << number << std::endl;
std::cout << "pointer: " << pointer << std::endl;

getchar();
```

this makes a exception, i know, but could someone properly explain those action to me? like *(int*) and *(DWORD*) etc.. or, recommend me a book? thanks!

Comment: Books are already recommended [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: but i couldnt any containing explaination of this..

Comment: Post a [MCVE] please, to give others a chance to reproduce your error. Thanks. What do you expect residing at address `0xA` actually?

Comment: its already posted in question

Comment: _"it's already posted in question"_ Nope, it doesn't conform the requirements, as from the given link.

Comment: I think you are asking about casting. If so, then this question has a good answer that covers this regular casting you are referring to. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast is my answer thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting or type conversion is changing a variable from one datatype to another.
There are two types. `implicit` and `explicit` casting.

`Implicit` type conversion, also known as `coercion`, is an automatic type conversion by the compiler.

```
double a = 3.4;
int b = a; //convert 'a' implicitly from 'double' to 'int'
```

`Explicit` type conversion is a type conversion which is explicitly defined within a program

```
int a = 3;
double b = (int)a; //convert 'a' explicitly from 'int' to 'double'
```

A `DWORD` is a 32-bit unsigned integer. I'ts just another type.
A pointer is another datatype.

```
void *a;
int *b = (int*)a; //explicit
void *c = b; //implicit
```

About cating: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Implicit_type_conversion
About book recommendation: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)