# C-style cast on a non-polymorphic type

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, downcast, type-punning

Suppose I have a base `struct` `FOO` which is essentially a C-style `struct`:

```
struct FOO
{
    double bar1;
    int bar2;
};
```

And a C++ style `struct` (which has member functions, no member data, but no v-table):

```
struct bar : public FOO
{
    double getBar1() const;
    int getBar2() const;
};
```

I then have a pointer `FOO* f`, which is *actually* a `FOO`: it was created using `FOO* f = new FOO()`;  Is the C-style cast `bar* b = (bar*)(f)` defined?

**Apologies: `bar` does not contain any data members**

Comment: The fact that `FOO` is a POD affects initialization in some cases. Inheritance and casting works the same way as any other class/struct

Comment: It is defined and works as static_cast<bar*>(f). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast

Comment: I don't like the duplicate since I make it very clear that the `struct`s are **not** polymorphic in my case.

Comment: @P45Imminent I’m not sure what *you* mean by “polymorphic” but as far as C++ is concerned, your struct is perfectly fit for polymorphic use — you don’t need a vtable for that.

Comment: Polymorphism has nothing to do with this (unless you use `dynamic_cast`). You might want to tell us if `f` actually points to a `FOO` or a `bar`. That affects the way you can use the `b`.

Comment: Sorry, I've clarified. `f` has been created using `new FOO()`. Also, by non-polymorphic I mean that you can't use `dynamic_cast` and there is no v-table (I believe the standard guarantees that will be no v-table).

Comment: The standard does not have a notion of vTable, but I'd be surprised if any compiler generated one indeed.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say is that I think the standard guarantees that the address of the first member is the same as the address of the struct for a non-polymorphic type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33124884/509868) by iammilind - your casting is the same as `static_cast`, and it's not defined.

The [Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) (the linked document is actually a draft, but it doesn't matter for most purposes) says "the result of the cast is undefined" in section 5.2.9, which describes `static_cast`.

However, since your `struct bar` has no data members, it's a *standard-layout* class, and it's *layout-compatible* with `struct FOO`. So you can cast your pointer to `void*` and then to `foo*`:

```
bar* b = (bar*)(void*)f
```

This is better represented in c++ by `reinterpret_cast`:

```
bar* b = reinterpret_cast<bar*>(f)
```

This is described in section 5.2.10:

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type ... the result is `static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v))` if both T1 and T2 are standard-layout types ...

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for invalidating your last draft. Can I cast straight to (bar*) or is it necessary to write (bar*)(void*)?

Comment: @P45Imminent My answer answers specifically that question - "Can I cast straight to (bar*) or is it necessary to write (bar*)(void*)?" - if you need a one-word answer, then **NO**. But there are some fine points. Please read both answers you got - my answer doesn't duplicate the useful info that the other answer has.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the C-style cast bar* b = (bar*)(f) defined?

C-Style casts will always work, that's why they are the worst among all the casts. For non-polymorphic classes, you may want to use `static_cast`.

However, in your case you are going towards **undefined behavior**.

```
bar* b = (bar*)(f);  // = static_cast<bar*>(f)
```

The type of `f` is `class FOO` (i.e. as in question `FOO* f = new FOO()`), not `class bar`. Hence you should not assign such pointers. Even if you assign, you must not use them as of they are of `class bar`.

<sub>P.S. IMO, safest to unsafe casts: `dynamic_cast`, `const_cast`, `static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, C-style cast.</sub>

Comment: I'd put `const_cast` as less safe than `static_cast`, as casting away `const`ness is UB if the original object is `const`. In many circumstances a compiler cannot warn you of that. It can *always* warn you about an improper `static_cast`.

Comment: @Bathsheba, I get what you are saying. For me `const_cast` and `static_cast` are usually in same category safety-wise. But `const_cast` has slightly upper hand because of its less vulnerability. It just deals with `const`s and that's too pointer or reference. But `static_cast` has a wider usage. It can happen between 2 classes belonging to inheritance hierarchy, `void*` to other pointers, as well as 2 integral types like `long` and `short`.  I don't think all of these have any compiler warning. So mantra is *less exploitation = more safety*.