# double typecast vs double function

Tags: c, casting

I've seen these two different ways to cast an `int` to a `double` in C:

```
double double_var = (double) int_var;
double double_var = double(int_var);
```

What's the difference between these two methods? When should I use one over the other?

Comment: One is valid C, the other isn't. Neither is necessary, since `double double_var = int_var;` already has the desired behaviour.

Comment: The first is syntactically correct C.  The second is syntactically invalid in C (but is correct in C++ and means the same as the first when written in C++ code).

Comment: .... Though, in C++ you try to avoid those vanilla casts and instead would rather write: ``static_cast<double>(int_var);``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143598/double-typecast-vs-double-function#comment58007312_35143598), the first is from C and the second from C++:

The first one is a C-style cast; the second is the instantiation of a `double` by passing the constructor an `int` value.

**So the second isn't really a cast but the creation of a new instance** (So it is more C++ than C).

If you only do some `C` then using constructors isn't relevant (there is no Object Oriented Programming in C, that's a C++ feature).

If you're doing some `C++` then you should avoid C-style casts (as @BitTickler stated) since problems can occure according the type of values you use it on. `C++` provides several casts types for several cases.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1255015/3156085) for further informations.