# Virtual method overrides in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual-functions, dynamic-dispatch

Assume we have an abstract class called `Vehicle`:

```
class Vehicle {
    virtual bool raceWith(Vehicle *anotherVehicle) = 0;
};
```

And we have its subclasses `Bicycle` and `Car`:

```
//  forward declaration
class Car;

class Bicycle : public Vehicle {
    virtual bool raceWith(Vehicle *anotherVehicle) {
        throw SomeExceptionClass();
    }

    virtual bool raceWith(Car *anotherVehicle) {
        return true;
    }

    virtual bool raceWith(Bicycle *anotherVehicle) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

However, this block of code throws SomeExceptionClass:

```
Vehicle *aBicycle = new Bicycle();
Vehicle *aCar = new Car();

aBicycle->raceWith(aCar);
```

What to do here? Does not C++ allow us to use polymorphic methods in this manner?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**: It will be also good to provide an answer with `dynamic_cast<>` and `decltype` variants?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will race a `Bicycle` with a `Vehicle`:

> ```
> Vehicle *aBicycle = new Bicycle();
> Vehicle *aCar = new Car();
>
> aBicycle->raceWith(aCar);
> ```

To race a `Bicycle` with a `Car` we need to use double dispatch.

To make double dispatch work we use the `this` pointer to call the next function so that the second virtual call can resolve to the correct type of vehicle:

```
class Car;
class Bicycle;

class Vehicle {
public:
    virtual bool raceWith(Vehicle& anotherVehicle) = 0;
    virtual bool raceWith(Bicycle& anotherVehicle) = 0;
    virtual bool raceWith(Car& anotherVehicle) = 0;
};


class Bicycle : public Vehicle {
public:
    virtual bool raceWith(Vehicle& anotherVehicle) override
    {
        //throw std::exception();
        return anotherVehicle.raceWith(*this);
    }

    virtual bool raceWith(Car& anotherVehicle)
    {
        return true;
    }

    virtual bool raceWith(Bicycle& anotherVehicle)
    {
        return false;
    }
};

class Car : public Vehicle {
public:
    virtual bool raceWith(Vehicle& anotherVehicle) override
    {
        return true;
    }

    virtual bool raceWith(Car& anotherVehicle) override
    {
        return true;
    }

    virtual bool raceWith(Bicycle& anotherVehicle) override
    {
        return false;
    }

};

int main()
{

    Vehicle *aBicycle = new Bicycle();
    Vehicle  *aCar = new Car();

    aBicycle->raceWith(*aCar);
}
```

Note the `return anotherVehicle.raceWith(*this);` which will perform the second virtual call.

The functions are then called in this order:

- `main();`
- `Bicycle::raceWith(Vehicle& anotherVehicle);`
- `Car::raceWith(Bicycle& anotherVehicle);`

---

The following is the same program, but sticking with the use of pointers and exceptions as provided in the question:

```
#include <exception>

class Car;
class Bicycle;

class Vehicle {
public:
    virtual bool raceWith(Vehicle* anotherVehicle) = 0;
    virtual bool raceWith(Bicycle* bicycle) = 0;
    virtual bool raceWith(Car* car) = 0;
};


class Bicycle : public Vehicle {
public:
    virtual bool raceWith(Vehicle* anotherVehicle) override
    {
        //throw std::exception();
        return anotherVehicle->raceWith(this);
    }

    virtual bool raceWith(Car* car) override
    {
        return true;
    }

    virtual bool raceWith(Bicycle* bicycle) override
    {
        return false;
    }
};

class Car : public Vehicle {
public:
    virtual bool raceWith(Vehicle* anotherVehicle) override
    {
        throw std::exception();
    }

    virtual bool raceWith(Car* car) override
    {
        return true;
    }

    virtual bool raceWith(Bicycle* bicycle) override
    {
        return false;
    }

};

int main()
{

    Vehicle *aBicycle = new Bicycle();
    Vehicle  *aCar = new Car();

    aBicycle->raceWith(aCar);
}
```

Comment: What is double dispatch?

Comment: @Leviathlon double virtual dispatching is the ability to call the correct implementation depending on the dynamic type of **two** objects. C++ only provides single virtual dispatching, on `this`. What flatmouse describes here is known as the Visitor pattern, and uses single dispatching twice to achieve double dispatching.

Comment: This solved the problem. Such a great answer. Thank you for attention.

Answer (score 1):

By doing

```
Vehicle *aBicycle = new Bicycle();
aBicycle->raceWith(aCar);
```

The type of aCar is Vehicle (`typeid(aCar).name()`), so your compiler is calling the method with Vehicle.

Try

```
aBicycle->raceWith(static_cast<Car*>(aCar));
aBicycle->raceWith(dynamic_cast<Car*>(aCar));
```

As for why `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`, you can look at this post on SO: [Regular cast vs. static_cast vs. dynamic_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast)

Comment: It was there sorry, I missed.

Comment: I had said **subclass**. Please do not provide this as an answer.

Comment: In object-oriented programming it has one definition. It never differs, unfortunately.

Comment: @Leviathlon I removed that part of my answer.

Comment: Again no, I found out this problem could be only solved with double dynamic dispatch.

Comment: @Leviathlon again no what? And why can this only be solved with double dispatch? Why so arrogant?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you can use dynamic cast to detect the type for subclass. If you keep `virtual bool raceWith(Vehicle *anotherVehicle)` as a method, probably `virtual bool raceWith(Car *anotherVehicle)` and `virtual bool raceWith(Bicycle *anotherVehicle)` will never get executed without casting since `anotherVehicle` is a Vehicle type obj. Hope will help :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Car;
class Bicycle;

class Vehicle {
    public:
     //virtual bool raceWith(Vehicle *anotherVehicle) = 0;
     virtual bool raceWith(Car *anotherVehicle) = 0;
     virtual bool raceWith(Bicycle *anotherVehicle) = 0;
};

class Bicycle : public Vehicle {
    /*virtual bool raceWith(Vehicle *anotherVehicle) {
        throw SomeExceptionClass();
    }*/
    virtual bool raceWith(Car *anotherVehicle) {
        cout << "will print" << endl;
        return true;
    }
    virtual bool raceWith(Bicycle *anotherVehicle) {
        return false;
    }
};
class Car : public Vehicle {
    /*virtual bool raceWith(Vehicle *anotherVehicle) {
        throw SomeExceptionClass();
    }*/
    virtual bool raceWith(Car *anotherVehicle) {
        return true;
    }

    virtual bool raceWith(Bicycle *anotherVehicle) {
        return false;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Vehicle *aBicycle = new Bicycle();
    Vehicle *aCar = new Car();

    if (dynamic_cast<Bicycle*>(aCar) != NULL) {
        std::cout << "Race with A Bicycle" << std::endl;
        aBicycle->raceWith(static_cast<Bicycle*>(aCar));
    }
    else if (dynamic_cast<Car*>(aCar) != NULL) {
        std::cout << "Race with A Car" << std::endl;
        aBicycle->raceWith(static_cast<Car*>(aCar));
    }
    else {
        //throw SomeExceptionClass();
    }

    //aBicycle->raceWith(aCar);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think, for what you are trying to achieve here, google -Visitor design pattern- will help you more