# How can I do XOR operation in Crypto++?

Tags: c++, encryption, aes, xor, crypto++

I want to perform XOR operation in AES before and after encryption in AES (like DESX) with new keys. But XOR operation takes too much time.

How can I reduce the XOR operation time?

Here is my code:

```
string XOR(string value, string key)
{
    string retval(value);

    short unsigned int klen=key.length();
    short unsigned int vlen=value.length();
    short unsigned int k=0;
    short unsigned int v=0;

    for(v;v<vlen;v++)
    {
        retval[v]=value[v]^key[k];
        k=(++k<klen?k:0);
    }

    return retval;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

    byte key1[AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH];
    prng.GenerateBlock(key1, sizeof(key1));

    byte key[AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH];
    prng.GenerateBlock(key, sizeof(key));

    byte key2[AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH];
    prng.GenerateBlock(key2, sizeof(key2));

    byte iv[AES::BLOCKSIZE];
    prng.GenerateBlock(iv, sizeof(iv));

    string plain = "AESX CBC Mode Test";
    string cipher,encoded, encodediv, encodedkey1, encodedkey, 
    encodedkey2, recovered, prerecovered, postrecovered, 
    prewhiten, postwhiten;

    // Pretty print key1
    StringSource(key1, sizeof(key1), true,
        new HexEncoder(
            new StringSink(encodedkey1)
        ) // HexEncoder
    ); // StringSource
    cout << "key1: " << encodedkey1 << endl;

    // Pretty print iv
    StringSource(iv, sizeof(iv), true,
        new HexEncoder(
            new StringSink(encodediv)
        ) // HexEncoder
    ); // StringSource
    cout << "iv: " << encodediv << endl;

    // Pretty print key
    StringSource(key, sizeof(key), true,
        new HexEncoder(
            new StringSink(encodedkey)
        ) // HexEncoder
    ); // StringSource
    cout << "key: " << encodedkey << endl;

    // Pretty print key2
    StringSource(key2, sizeof(key2), true,
        new HexEncoder(
            new StringSink(encodedkey2)
        ) // HexEncoder
    ); // StringSource
    cout << "key2: " << encodedkey2 << endl;

    cout << "plain text: " << plain << endl;

    prewhiten = XOR(plain, encodedkey1);

    try
    {
        cout << "pre whiten text: " << prewhiten << endl;

        CBC_Mode< AES >::Encryption e;
        e.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv);

        // The StreamTransformationFilter removes
        //  padding as required.
        StringSource s(prewhiten, true, 
            new StreamTransformationFilter(e,
                new StringSink(cipher)
            ) // StreamTransformationFilter
        ); // StringSource

    }
    catch(const CryptoPP::Exception& e)
    {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    /*********************************\
    \*********************************/

    // Pretty print
    encoded.clear();
    StringSource(cipher, true,
        new HexEncoder(
            new StringSink(encoded)
        ) // HexEncoder
    ); // StringSource
    cout << "cipher text: " << encoded << endl;

    postwhiten = XOR(encoded, encodedkey2);

    cout << "post whiten text: " << postwhiten << endl;

    //decryption

    prerecovered = XOR(postwhiten, encodedkey2);

    encoded.clear();
    StringSource(prerecovered, true,
        new HexEncoder(
            new StringSink(encoded)
        ) // HexEncoder
    ); // StringSource

    cout << "pre recovered text: " << encoded << endl;

    try
    {
        CBC_Mode< AES >::Decryption d;
        d.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv);

        // The StreamTransformationFilter removes
        //  padding as required.
        StringSource s(prerecovered, true, 
            new HexDecoder(
                new StreamTransformationFilter(d,
                    new StringSink(recovered)
                ) // StreamTransformationFilter
            )//HexDecoder
        ); // StringSource

        cout << "recovered text: " << recovered << endl;
    }
    catch(const CryptoPP::Exception& e)
    {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    postrecovered = XOR(recovered, encodedkey1);

    cout << "post recovered text: " << postrecovered << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: XOR takes far less time than reading or writing a word from memory.

Comment: `k=(++k<klen?k:0);`  could be `k=(++k)%klen;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I do XOR operation in Crypto++?

There are two ways to use the library to perform an XOR. First, there are two  functions [`xorbuf`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/misc.cpp#L28) in `misc.h`. The first implementation is shown below, and it uses a single in/out buffer with a mask:

```
void xorbuf(byte *buf, const byte *mask, size_t count)
{
    size_t i=0;
    if (IsAligned<word32>(buf) && IsAligned<word32>(mask))
    {
        if (!CRYPTOPP_BOOL_SLOW_WORD64 && IsAligned<word64>(buf) && IsAligned<word64>(mask))
        {
            for (i=0; i<count/8; i++)
                ((word64*)(void*)buf)[i] ^= ((word64*)(void*)mask)[i];
            count -= 8*i;
            if (!count)
                return;
            buf += 8*i;
            mask += 8*i;
        }

        for (i=0; i<count/4; i++)
            ((word32*)(void*)buf)[i] ^= ((word32*)(void*)mask)[i];
        count -= 4*i;
        if (!count)
            return;
        buf += 4*i;
        mask += 4*i;
    }

    for (i=0; i<count; i++)
        buf[i] ^= mask[i];
}
```

There's a second `xorbuf(byte *output, const byte *input, const byte *mask, size_t count)` that uses separate in and out buffers with a mask.

The second way to XOR is use an `ArrayXorSink` from [`filters.h`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/filters.cpp#L565). Internally, `ArrayXorSink` calls `xorbuf` for you. You would use this is you prefer [pipelines](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pipelining).

```
size_t ArrayXorSink::Put2(const byte *begin, size_t length, int messageEnd, bool blocking)
{
    // Avoid passing NULL pointer to xorbuf
    size_t copied = 0;
    if (m_buf && begin)
    {
        copied = STDMIN(length, SaturatingSubtract(m_size, m_total));
        xorbuf(m_buf+m_total, begin, copied);
    }
    m_total += copied;
    return length - copied;
}
```

---

> ```
> string XOR(string value, string key)
> {
>     string retval(value);
>
>     short unsigned int klen=key.length();
>     short unsigned int vlen=value.length();
>     short unsigned int k=0;
>     short unsigned int v=0;
>
>     for(v;v<vlen;v++)
>     {
>         retval[v]=value[v]^key[k];
>         k=(++k<klen?k:0);
>     }
>
>     return retval;
> }
> ```

For this, you could do something like the following. It asks the compiler to `inline` the function, and it passes the `value` and `key` by constant reference to avoid the copies.

```
inline string XOR(const string& value, const string& key)
{
    ASSERT(key.length() == value.length());

    string retval(value);
    xorbuf(&retval[0], &key[0], retval.length());
    return retval; 
}
```

The trick is, you have to take the address of element 0 to get the non-const pointer and avoid potential undefined behavior. You may need to cast to a `byte*`.

---

> How can I reduce the XOR operation time?

You probably want to use an operand size larger that 1-byte when its feasible. The library's `xorbuf` uses `word32` and `word64` when available.

In addition, if you have AVX, then you can operate on buffers up to 512-bit. If you keep your buffers aligned, then GCC will try use the larger buffers at `-O3` and above. `-O3` is significant because that's when GCC starts aggressive vectorization and using features provided by AVX and AVX2.

The Crypto++ library endured a non-trivial amount of pain a couple of years ago because its buffers were not aligned as GCC expected, and it was causing SEGFAULT's `-O3` and above. See, for example, [Crash on Cygwin i386 with -O3](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cryptopp-users/AUKPXDduHww/lk0AE9fAVKcJ).

The alignment problem was not limited to Cygwin; Cygwin happened to demonstrate it. The problem surfaced on occasion under other platforms and CPUs, like ARM when NEON was enabled. We believe all the issues have been cleared.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer jww. Is there a way to xor strings in crypto++? After encryption given result is string.

Comment: @T.Rifle - use `xorbuf` as discussed above.

Comment: jww - I am very new in c++, so sorry for the question. How to cast a byte? It's given error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘byte* {aka unsigned char*}’ [-fpermissive]

Comment: @T.Rifle - See [When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/332030/608639) and [Regular cast vs. static_cast vs. dynamic_cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28002/608639).