# How to warn about incompatible type for argument on void pointer in C?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

In a example below, I want to know the call of `func` with a wrong type of argument - `vptr`, which should be called with an `int` pointer.

```
void func(int * ptr){
}
int main(){
    void * vptr;
    func(vptr);
}
```

GCC doesn't warn this type of warnings even with wall option. Is there any other options in gcc, or other programming tricks of finding out those bad manners of codes.
Aside that, how about in cpp?

EDIT:
VTT answered this is valid in C, but invalid in C++ with no other cast keywords like `static_cast` ([see the other post in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast)).

Comment: For g++ use: `-fpermissive` as in 
_"main.cpp 6 error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]"_

Comment: Also try using `-Wextra -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align`.

Comment: My SO g++ build options: `-Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wshadow -Winit-self -Wredundant-decls -Wcast-align -Wundef -Wfloat-equal -Wunreachable-code -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wswitch-enum -Wswitch-default -Weffc++ -Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant -Wmain -pedantic-errors -pedantic -Wextra -Wall`  try them all, remove the ones that start to annoy you.

Comment: @Ric Some (many?) of those are implied by either -Wall or -Wextra

Comment: @Andre Those options were in no effect in C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C, it's a valid implicit conversion. In C++, such conversion requires at least `static_cast` and causes compile-time error otherwise. You should figure out which language are you actually using.

Comment: This is asking for clarification of the question; it should be a comment.

Comment: in C++ you would use static_cast

Comment: @M.M well, `static_cast` can be used indeed, however using it may lead to strict aliasing violation.

Comment: @VTT (a) the type of cast has nothing to do with strict aliasing , (b) in this instance reinterpret_cast is defined to have the same behaviour as static_cast, but it's good practice to use the "smallest hammer"