# std shared_pointer_cast not defined

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I am trying a sample example noted down in apache arrow C++ [example](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/cpp/apidoc/index.md).
The example uses shared pointed cast as below (code snippet)

**Version**

```
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3aka8.0.2) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

**Code**

```
int main()
{
        Int64Builder builder(arrow::default_memory_pool(), arrow::int64());
        builder.Append(8);

        std::shared_ptr<Array> array;
        builder.Finish(&array);

        std::shared_ptr<Int64Array> int64_array = std::shared_pointer_cast<Int64Array>(array);


        return 0;
}
```

**Compilation Flags**

However, when I compile the code with below flags, I get undefined error.

```
g++ example.cpp -O2 -std=c++11 -I/workspace/arrow/arrow-master/cpp/src  -L/workspace/arrow/arrow-master/cpp/release/release  -larrow -larrow_jemalloc
```

**Error**

```
example.cpp: In function 'int main()':
example.cpp:24:44: error: 'shared_pointer_cast' is not a member of 'std'
  std::shared_ptr<Int64Array> int64_array = std::shared_pointer_cast<Int64Array>(array);
                                            ^
example.cpp:24:79: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
  std::shared_ptr<Int64Array> int64_array = std::shared_pointer_cast<Int64Array>(array);
```

I do not see any documentation for `std::shared_pointer_cast`

**Question**

1. Am I missing something, is this compilable code in c++11 version?
2. What are the alternative in C++11 version for this?

Comment: The example likely meant [`std::static_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast

Comment: @songyuanyao: The link quoted does not have reference to shared_pointer_cast. Note that the example does not quote static_pointer_cast.

Comment: @kumar_m_kiran There's no such thing of `std::shared_pointer_cast`; the example is wrong..? Or it's just an abstract wording, which includes `std::static_pointer_cast`, `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`, `std::const_pointer_cast`, `std::reinterpret_pointer_cast`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `static_pointer_cast` or a `dynamic_pointer_cast` based on what your intention is.

Here are all the casts supported in C++ 11:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast

But, there is nothing called a `std::shared_pointer_cast` in C++11

Additionally [static_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) should work for you. Try `static_cast` instead of the `std::shared_pointer_cast`

**Important points to consider when using casts:**

`static_cast` performs no runtime checks. This should be used if you know that you refer to an object of a specific type, and thus a check would be unnecessary. It is also used to avoid the implicit conversion & rather make it explicit

`dynamic_cast` is used for cases where you don't know what the dynamic type of the object is. You cannot use dynamic_cast if you downcast and the argument type is not polymorphic. An example:

`Regular cast` is a C-Style cast which combines all of `const_cast`, `static_cast` and `reinterpret_cast`, but it's also unsafe.

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast) to understand more about casts used in C++.