# Understanding Casts in C++11

Tags: c++11, casting

I'm trying to understand these lines of code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


struct Foo {};
struct Bar {};



int main()
{
    Foo* f = new Foo;

    Bar* b1 = f; //error

    Bar* b2 = static_cast<Bar*>(f); //error

    Bar* b3 = dynamic_cast<Bar*>(f); //error

    Bar* b4 = reinterpret_cast<Bar*>(f);

    Bar* b5 = const_cast<Bar*>(f); //error


    return 0;
}
```

Please, could you explain to me why the marked lines don't compile?

In addition, if `reinterpret_cast` was designed to deal with pointers, why should you use `static_cast` with pointers? Shouldn't it be used to cast objects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular cast vs. static\_cast vs. dynamic\_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please could you explain me why that marked lines don't compile?

The reason your code is not compiling is the fact that Foo and Bar are **unrelated data types**

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/typecasting/)

> **dynamic_cast** can be used only with pointers and references to objects. Its purpose is to ensure that the result of the type conversion is a valid complete object of the requested class.
>
> Therefore, dynamic_cast is always successful when we cast a class to one of its **base classes**

whereas

> **static_cast** can perform conversions between pointers to **related** classes, not only from the derived class to its base, but also from a base class to its derived

and

> **const_cast** manipulates the **constness** of an object, either to be set or to be removed

The **reinterpret_cast**, however, is the only choice you have for making things work:

> **reinterpret_cast** converts *any* pointer type to *any* other pointer type, **even of unrelated classes**. The operation result is a simple binary copy of the value from one pointer to the other.
>
> **All pointer conversions are allowed**: neither the content pointed nor the pointer type itself is checked.

There's no relationship between your two structs Foo and Bar, so the **reinterpret_cast** is the only choise available to you in this case.

If you take a look at the link I put above, you will see (*in the reinterpret_cast section)* the same identical example you provided.