# Not a polymorphic type or why do we need virtual destructors here?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual, multiple-inheritance, dynamic-cast

Currently I am learning about dynamic casting and thus I am testing out various code snippets.

I tested below's code with and without the virtual destructors marked in (2) and found that line (3) is only correct, if there is line (2). Without it, the code does not compile. But why? Interestingly line (1) doesn't seem to be needed at all.

```
struct A {
    virtual ~A() = default; \\ (1)
};
struct B {
    virtual ~B() = default; \\ (2)
};
struct D : A, B {};

B* pb = new D();
A* pa = dynamic_cast<A*>(pb); \\ (3)
```

Comment: Are you asking why `dynamic_cast` only works on polymorphic types?

Comment: It would help me to know: Why is the destructor in (2) without the virtual modifier not a polymorphic type?

Comment: Because polymorphism means run time (dynamic) binding <=> virtual functions.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis, you can also have static polymorphism, e.g. via CRTP. So not every polymormisphm has to be dynamic.

Comment: @Imago With the CRTP a `static_cast<Derived*>(this)` is used, because `dynamic_cast` won't work well with that pattern.

Comment: "polymorphic type" has a special meaning C++. It means "a class with at least one virtual function (possibly inherited)".

Answer (score 0):

#### In general

[`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) requires to determine the behavior at run-time.  Depending on the **real type** of the casted object, it will either return `nullptr` or a valid pointer of the target type.

For this to happen at run-time, the C++ implementation needs to have access to some additional [information about the type at run-time](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/storage-layout-of-polymorphic-objects/240012098).  And managing this information require some additional operations to be performed.  The overhead is minimal but it exist.

Dynamic casting is not always needed.  The C++ language designer has decided not to create unnecessary overhead if it is not needed.  So unless you say that polymorphism is needed, the compiler will try to solve all the type questions as much as possible at compile-time.

The way to say that **polymorphism** and dynamic typing is needed is to have **at least one virtual member function** in the class.

#### Your specific case

If you'd know in your program very well that the source object's type is compatible with the target object type, you could use `static_cast` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28002/3723423).

But this will not work in your case, since `pb` is a `*B` (static type), because in general a `*B` cannot be casted to an `*A` because both types are completely unrelated.

But a `*D` (dynamic type) can be casted to an `*A` in view of its multiple inheritance. And this is why `dynamic_cast` is needed here: to keep track of the original D type of the objet that pb points to.  And this requires the class to have at least a virtual function as explained above.

Comment: "_The C++ language designer has decided not to create unnecessary overhead if it is not needed_" It's called "don't pay for what you don't use" and frequently mentioned in the design of C++. It isn't an absolute principe, if supporting a feature as a very moderate cost at program startup (even for code that doesn't use it), the cost won't be a good argument against the feature. And some library components have some inefficiencies even if you don't use the "advanced" feature.

Comment: (...) Many core features have cost for code that don't use them. Supporting exception (even in functions that don't throw or catch any exception) requires either a (non trivial) decrease of efficiency of code that only has normal returns, or a (non trivial) increase of code size to describe the objects that need to be destroyed. (The support of almost zero runtime cost for exception handling until an exception is thrown, by many C++ compilers, makes C++ is a good assembly-like language for compilers of high level languages that have exceptions that want portability.)

Comment: (...) Being able to safely construct a function static object in the presence of threads has a cost even if multiple threads aren't ever created, or if static objects are constructed without a race condition, before multiple threads startup. The potential of sharing an object with "smart pointers" (like `std::shared_ptr`) requires the use of atomic operation for the refcount. Some programs even those that use threads will not have any objects shared between threads (sharing of mutable objects requires other precaution by the user and you really want to know whether it can occur).

Comment: @curiousguy Indeed, and this design rule is also called the "*zero overhead rule*" (page 121 of Stroustrup's book "*The design and evolution of the C++ language*", just before the "*If in doubt, provide means for manual control*"-rule). We could of course discuss whether or not programmers are forced to use shared pointers (other C++ design rule:  "*Don't try to force people*") or exception handling (see [noexcept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec)) if they think they can't afford the overhead.  But how are these of your comments related to the OP's question ?

Comment: 1) Using `noexcept` only removes the need to exception handling by the compiled code *if every single function called is noexcept* (or good old `throw()`, which was denigrated for no reason what so ever). 2) What is the "manual control" on construction of static variables? Can you have them constructed in a non MT safe way? 3) Many classes will have their ctor initialize members even if it isn't needed (think `complex`, `pair`) because they can be left uninitialized until a value is assigned. Although for local simple objects the cost is mostly trivial, for large arrays it can be nontrivial.

Comment: In C++ you can't have a user defined type such that `T()` is zero initialized but `T x;` isn't. **The "zero overhead rule" simply isn't practical in a feature rich, multi purpose language like C++.** It isn't even a general guidance of language design. It's an ideal goal, not a practical goal. **In many area C++ practically imposes overhead on features that may not be needed** and there is no simple standard construct to avoid the cost, or no feature all at. Sometimes you can compiler w/o exception support, RTTI support, MT support (but if just one component uses the feature you can't).

Comment: "_We could of course discuss whether or not programmers are forced to use shared pointers_" That really was not the question. When an object is shared by multiple entities such that it cannot be known in advance which one will release it last, some kind of refcounting is needed and a shared smart pointer is recommended. My point was that `shared_ptr` uses atomic increment (relaxed) and decrement (ack_rel) for the two RC even if you don't share an object between threads. There are very few cases where compilers can optimize out atomics when compiled with MT support.

Comment: @curiousguy This whole question is not about shared pointers and neither about their atomic increments. It’s not even about the standard library. So imho your comments seem somewhat out of scope. If you have a better or more accurate answer, don’t hesitate to provide your own constructive answer instead of commenting further this one.

Comment: The comments are in the scope of your answer more than the scope of the Q. You assert that C++ follows a "don't pay for what you don't use" principle but it really doesn't as many examples prove.

Comment: "_don’t hesitate to provide your own constructive answer_" I will