# Casting with structs c++

Tags: c++, struct

Can I simply cast a Parent-struct in a child-struct in c++?

I tried to cast:

```
Base s;
Child tmp = (Child)s;
```

and got this error:
No matching conversion for C-style cast from ...

Can anyone help me to solve this error?

Comment: You can, if you declared a `Child::Child(Base const &)` constructor. The C-style cast is unnecessary though, just do `Child tmp(s);`.

Comment: No. The child may have extra members that don't exist in the base class. Where would their values come from?

Comment: "_Can I simply cast a Parent-struct in a child-struct in c++?_" No. `s` is not a `Child. Consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I would highly suggest looking through the [c++ casting question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332030/332733) C style casts are incredibly dangerous.

Comment: You cast on the wrong direction, a Child is a Base but not the reverse. May be also you wanted to work on pointer ?

Answer (score 0):

A struct is a type consisting of a sequence of members whose storage is allocated in an ordered sequence If the sequence is a mismatch, the conversion may not work.

Within a struct object, addresses of its elements (and the addresses of the bit field allocation units) increase in order in which the members were defined. A pointer to a struct can be cast to a pointer to its first member (or, if the member is a bit field, to its allocation unit). Likewise, a pointer to the first member of a struct can be cast to a pointer to the enclosing struct. There may be unnamed padding between any two members of a struct or after the last member, but not before the first member. The size of a struct is at least as large as the sum of the sizes of its members.

First of all, If you are using c++. Why would you like to perform c style casting between `Base`  and `Child`?

C++ provided `static_cast` for non-polymorphic conversion and `dynamic_cast` for the polymorphic conversion.

There is more info about these casts:
[Regular cast vs. static_cast vs. dynamic_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast/28026#28026)?